# Pasar Datos de Fragments hacia Fragments en otra activity

Tags: android

Tengo un problema que me tiene mi aplicación detenida.
Tengo una activity con varios fragments de los que necesito al disparar el evento de uno de los botones del menú, recoger sus datos y enviarlos a otra activity para mostrarlos en los fragments para dicha activity.

Comment: Podrías compartir algo más de información: ¿cuál es la estructura de la app?¿cómo es el código que utilizas en el botón para recoger los datos? ¿Tienes el problema al recoger los datos o al mandarlos a la otra activity? Si has intentado algo y falló, ¿qué error recibiste?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simplemente envia los datos que tienes en el fragment a travez de un bundle, cuando sean recibidos por la segunda actividad puedes usarlos en su respectivo fragment.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),SegundaActividad.class);
intent.putExtra("dato_bundle", bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

en la segunda Activity, dentro de tu método onCreate():

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String valorRecibido= getIntent().getStringExtra("dato_bundle");
```

Aquí recibiendo los datos del bundle, pueden ser utilizados en el fragmento que tiene tu segunda actividad.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes usar:

> putString(String key, Size value)

En el Fragment Origen antes de procesar beginTransaction()

```
Bundle args = new Bundle(); 
args.putString("email", email);
fragment.setArguments(args);
```

En el onCreateView del Fragment destino puedes obtener el/los y guardarlos donde quieras.

```
String EMAIL = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getString("email") : "email@email.com";
```

Puedes enviar más, cuantos necesites:

```
args.putString("email", email);
args.putString("nombre", nombre);
args.putString("edad", edad);
args.putString("sexo", sexo);
```

Claro ademas de tambien puedes pasar otros tipos de datos (String, int, float, etc)

Ver: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/os/Bundle.html

Answer (score 1):

Yo tambien he tenido ese problema!

Cuando quieres pasar DATA entre dos Fragments, se debe de utilizar la clase `Bundle` (paquete en español, en terminologia de computacion) una vez creada, hay que añadirle pues un .putString(Key, Value), .putInt(Key, Value)...

Y en el otro `Fragment` donde recibes la data, haces un     `Bundle b = getArguments();` y despues si es un int, por ejemplo haces un `b.getInt(Key,valorPorDefecto)`