# ¿Cómo enviar datos entre activities?

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo un problema. Tengo dos `activities`, la principal y una segunda pantalla. Quiero que la segunda pantalla le mande datos a la pantalla principal pero cuando inicio la aplicación me dice que se detuvo y se cierra. Cuando lo hago al revés (De la página principal a la segunda pantalla) funciona sin problemas.

¿Alguien sabe porque el error? ¿Para pasar los datos estoy usando `Bundle`, es la forma correcta o hay una mejor?

**Pantalla principal**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView tv2;
Button b2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv2);
    b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b2); 

    Bundle parametros = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    String datos = parametros.getString("datos"); 
    tv2.setText(datos);
}

public void segunda_pantalla(View view){
    Intent i=new Intent(this, segunda_pantalla.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

**Segunda Pantalla**:

```
public class pantalla2 extends AppCompatActivity {

Button b1;
TextView tv1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pantalla2);

    b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
    tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
}

public void b1(View view){

    tv1.setText("1");

    String datos = tv1.getText().toString();

    Bundle parmetros = new Bundle();
    parmetros.putString("datos", datos);

    Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    i.putExtras(parmetros);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: Hola, nose el error, cuando inicio la app me dice que se detuvo y se cierra

Comment: En la primera pantalla tienes un nullpointerexception de libro ,  Bundle parametros = this.getIntent().getExtras();

Comment: Las respuestas que te dieron son válidas. Lo que si me gustaría agregar es que quizás debas analizar utilizar fragmentos, son menos costosos y te dan una UI fluida. Por otra parte es a lo que Android apunta a con jetpack hoy, 1 actividad simple que solo inicia un navigator y después las vistas en fragmentos. Los pases entre vistas se hacen mucho más fluidos (cada actividad tiene un set de recursos asociados que deben cargarse al iniciar, el fragmento trabaja sobre una actividad)

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Pasar objetos entre actividades Android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/215399/pasar-objetos-entre-actividades-android)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Como enviar datos entre Actividades.**

Para realizar el envió de datos se realiza generalmente mediante un `Bundle` en el cual se pueden agregar valores y ese `bundle` se envía a través de un `Intent`. Se puede especificar el envió de cualquier tipo de elemento o array de elemento especificando el nombre:

```
    intent.putExtra("usuario", "StackOverflow!");
    intent.putExtra("id", 123);
    intent.putExtra("myByte", 0xa);
    intent.putExtra("latitud", 0.12324234);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Los valores se obtienen en la `Activity` que recibe el `Bundle` mediante [getExtras()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getExtras()) o el [método especifico para obtener tipo de dato recibido](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html). Retorna null si no encuentra valor.

```
String valor = getIntent().getExtras().getString("usuario");
```

o simplemente:

```
String valor = getIntent().getStringExtra("usuario");
```

**Importante: es importante mencionar que la recepción de la información en la `Activity` destino debe realizarse siempre dentro del método `onCreate()`** .

---

**Tu problema sucede porque al iniciar `MainActivity` intenta recibir un bundle el cual tiene valor `null`, lo puedes verificar en el LogCat.**

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
> at MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java)

Realiza la siguiente validación:

```
 Bundle parametros = this.getIntent().getExtras();
 if(parametros !=null){
    String datos = parametros.getString("datos"); 
   tv2.setText(datos);
 }
```

toma en cuenta que en la actividad que no asegures reciba un `Bundle`, tienes que realizar esta validación.

Además, es importante comentar que para regresar a la primera `Activity` no necesitas realizarlo por medio de un `Intent`, simplemente usa `finish()` para cerrarla.

---

**Para enviar datos entre activies se hace uso de la clase [Bundle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle)**

Se puede usar el método `putExtra()` para adjuntar números enteros, valores de coma flotante, bytes, caracteres y algunos otros tipos de datos que se enumeran en la documentación oficial de desarrolladores de Android. Para recuperar estos valores del `Intent` en la `Activity` receptora, Servicio o `Broadcast Receiver` se usa el método `getExtra()`.

Así mismo, podemos almacenar cualquier número de pares clave-valor en un objeto `Bundle` y simplemente pasar este objeto a través del `Intent`:

```
Bundle extras = new Bundle();

extras.putString("USUARIO","jhon Doe"); // se obtiene el valor mediante getString(...)
extras.putInt("USUARIO_ID", 21); // se obtiene el valor mediante getInt(...)
extras.putBoolean("HABILITADO", true); // se obtiene el valor mediante getBoolean(...)

Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
//Agrega el objeto bundle a el Intne
intent.putExtras(extras);
//Inicia Activity
startActivity(intent);
```

otros tipos que pueden ser enviados:

```
extras.putByte(key, Byte.parseByte(value)); // se obtiene el valor mediante getByte(...)
extras.putChar(key, value.charAt(0)); // se obtiene el valor mediante getChar(...)
extras.putDouble(key, Double.parseDouble(value)); // se obtiene el valor mediante getDouble(...)
extras.putFloat(key, Float.parseFloat(value)); // se obtiene el valor mediante getFloat(...)
extras.putLong(key, Long.parseLong(value)); // se obtiene el valor mediante getLong(...)
extras.putShort(key, Short.parseShort(value)); // se obtiene el valor mediante getShort(...)
```

---

Otras preguntas similares en el sitio que te serían de gran ayuda:

- **[Pasar Datos de Fragments hacia Fragments en otra activity](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/5653/pasar-datos-de-fragments-hacia-fragments-en-otra-activity/5725#5725)**
- **[Ayuda con android studio diversas activitys,obtencion de datos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/32922/ayuda-con-android-studio-diversas-activitys-obtencion-de-datos/32965#32965)**

Comment: todos tus argumentos son validos, sin embargo si te fijas cuando regresa a la actividad principal desde la segunda lo hace con startActivity(); lo cual no es recomendable.

Comment: Se trata de enviar valores por eso el uso de startActivity() , no de enviar y recibir un valor usando startActivityForResult(), porque no es recomendable lo que sugiero en mi respuesta?

Answer (score 4):

Esa no es la forma correcta de recibir los datos, existe un método llamado `startActivityForResult()`:

```
public void segunda_pantalla(View view){
    Intent i=new Intent(this, segunda_pantalla.class);
    startActivityForResult(i, 1);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1) { // el "1" es el numero que pasaste como parametro
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            String result=data.getStringExtra("datos");
            // tu codigo para continuar procesando
            tv2.setText(datos);
        }
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // código si no hay resultado
        }
    }
}//onActivityResult
```

y para retornar datos desde la segunda actividad:

```
public void b1(View view){
    tv1.setText("1");

    String datos = tv1.getText().toString();

    //Bundle parmetros = new Bundle();
    //parmetros.putString("datos", datos);
    //Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    //i.putExtras(parmetros);
    //startActivity(i);

    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
    returnIntent.putExtra("datos",datos);
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
    finish();
}
```

Y la aplicación se detiene por que cuando ejecutas la app la primera vez esta pidiendo datos en el `onCreate()` pero no existen tales datos:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv2);
    b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b2); 

    //Bundle parametros = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    //String datos = parametros.getString("datos"); 
    //tv2.setText(datos);
}
```

Aquí un poco de la [Documentación oficial de StartActivity() y StartActivityForResult()](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)

**Nota** La función `finish()` se debe usar casi de manera obligatoria, de otro modo cuando entres en la segunda actividad y te retorne a la primera estarás ciclandote entre actividades, esto se puede probar cuando presionas el back button te regresará a la segunda actividad, luego a la primera y al final saldra de la aplicación.

**Dato curioso**: Si revisas el [Ciclo de vida de las actividades](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) te darás cuenta que cuando se ejecuta una segunda actividad la actividad actual se pone en `onPause()` por lo tanto cuando regresas a la actividad principal se ejecuta el metodo `onResume()` en lugar de `onCreate()`. (Solo son algunos consejos para optimizar tu código)

Comment: Se trata de enviar valores por eso el uso de startActivity() , no de enviar y recibir un valor usando startActivityForResult() , no es necesario.

Answer (score 3):

En la primera actividad tienes que comprobar que tu variable `paremetros` no sea nula

```
Bundle parametros = this.getIntent().getExtras();
```

Prueba algo así

```
 Bundle parametros = this.getIntent().getExtras();
 if(parametros != null) {  
 String datos = parametros.getString("datos"); 
 tv2.setText(datos);}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yo lo realizaria de la siguiente manera 
Activity 2

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
i.putExtras("datos", datos);
startActivity(i);
```

Y en MainActivity lo recibo

```
Intent recibir = getIntent();
String datos = recibir.getStringExtra("datos");
```

Listo ya los tienes

Comment: eso no resuelve el problema por que los datos los recibe en onCreate y cuando la actividad principal se ejecute primero el intent estará vacio

Comment: la verdad no se si le funcione solo aporto una idea de como yo lo haria, Gracias por tus sugerencias

Answer (score 0):

```
 val intent = Intent(this, InfoAddNamesActivity::class.java).apply {
                putExtra("name", name.text.toString())
                **putStringArrayListExtra("childs",childs)**
            }
```

Y lo captas asi:

```
listChilds = intent.getSerializableExtra("childs") as ArrayList<String>
```