# Pasar parámetros de un asynctask

Tags: android

Estoy realizando un proyecto en android que contiene un login. Para buscar a los usuarios se conecta a un servicio wcf y todo funciona perfecto, pero necesito obtener el nombre de usuario para hacer validaciones.

Para consumir el wcf uso un asynctask pero no sé cómo obtener el contenido de la variable usuario y poder usarla en otros activity's.

Este es el asynctask donde consumo el wcf (LoginActivity):

```
public class GetUsuario extends android.os.AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/IService1/listarUsuario";
    final String METHOD = "listarUsuario";
    final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    final String ENDPOINTWS = "http://192.1.1.53/SP_Inventarios_Dummy/Service1.svc";
    int j = 0;

    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    public GetUsuario(LoginActivity activity) {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog.setMessage("Iniciando...");
        dialog.show();
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        listaTodo.clear();
        SoapObject userRequest = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD);
        userRequest.addProperty("user", params[0]);
        userRequest.addProperty("pass", params[1]);

        usuario = params[0].toString();
        password = params[1].toString();

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(userRequest);
        envelope.dotNet = true;

        try {
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(ENDPOINTWS);
            androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

            SoapObject res = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
            SoapObject t = (SoapObject) res.getProperty("listarUsuarioResult");

            for (int i = 0; i < t.getPropertyCount(); i++) {
                SoapObject bank = (SoapObject) t.getProperty(i);

                String busuario = bank.getProperty("Nombre_Usuario").toString();
                String bpassword = bank.getProperty("Password_Usuario").toString();
                String bdepto = bank.getProperty("Departamento").toString();


                Usuarios usu = new Usuarios(busuario, bpassword, bdepto);
                listaTodo.add(usu);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

        String sUser = user.getText().toString();
        String sPass = pass.getText().toString();

               if (listaTodo.get(0).strNombre_Usuario.equals(sUser)
                       && listaTodo.get(0).strPassword_Usuario.equals(sPass)) {
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bienvenido", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                   Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class );
                   startActivity(i);
               }
               else {
                       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nombre de usuario o contraseña incorrectas", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

               }
    }

}
```

Ahora lo que quiero hacer es tomar el parámetro de usuario para hacer validaciones y mostrar información pero en otro Activity.

Comment: tienes conocimientos de `XML` o `JSON` ? son los lenguajes para poder consumir los servicios, sea tmb tus servicios de `WCF`.

Comment: Sí, consumo mi servicio por medio de ksoap

Comment: Entonces primero debes aprender a parsear dichos elementos o lo que te traiga tu servicio, en este caso los datos del usuario.
Aquí un pequeño link http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: Ya luego desde tu aplicación guardarlos, puedes usar `Preferences` o `SQLite`

Comment: Si no agregas tu código tu pregunta parece un poco amplia... =(

Comment: Dentro de : doInBackground() obtienes valor para busuario aquí :  String busuario = bank.getProperty("Nombre_Usuario").toString();

Answer (score -1):

Ya quedó solucionado, utilicé este pequeño fragmento de código para que me guardará los datos que ocupaba:

```
public void ejecutar(View view) {
     Intent i = new Intent(this, Actividad2.class );
     i.putExtra("direccion", et1.getText().toString());
     startActivity(i);        
}
```

Y ya en el otro activity:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    webView1.loadUrl("http://" + bundle.getString("direccion"));
```

Lo adapté a mis necesidades y funcionó.

Comment: Hola Sandra, podrías explicar un poco más tu solución, sucede que las respuestas tipo link en ocasiones son borradas =(

Comment: Entonces sólo querías pasar parámetros de una actividad a otra ? claro usando `Asynctask`

Comment: Dupe de : https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36902/pasar-datos-entre-activities/36924#36924