# ¿Cómo evitar doble logueo en Android?

Tags: android, wordpress, login

Tengo una aplicación Android que para acceder a ella tengo que loguearme, ya dentro de la app tengo una actividad que contiene un webview en el cual visualizo una página web en wordpress, sin embargo, para poder visualizar el contenido me pide loguearme nuevamente con los datos iniciales del app. ¿Sabrán si existe una forma de evitar ese segundo login? ¿Cómo podría pasar los parametros de logueo de la actividad de login de mi app al webview y asi evitar que me vuelva a loguear?

Answer (score 0):

Si accedes a una `Activity` y posteriormente cargas otra con un `WebView` puedes enviar los datos para que sean usados en el `WebView`.

[Pasar datos entre activities](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36902/pasar-datos-entre-activities/36924#36924)

Si el WebView carga una página Wordpress con usuario/password, podrías intentar enviando esos mismos datos a la página que cargas.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_password

Esto suponiendo que el usuario/password es el mismo en ambos casos.