# Abrir una nueva pantalla, con un un onMenuItemClick y enviar datos

Tags: android, recyclerview, click

Buenas, tengo un `RecyclerView` con sus `CardView`, y cuando pincho encima de la foto me sale el menu desplegable que he creado con 2 opciones.

Con una de ellas deseo poder abrir otra actividad para mostrar mas informacion.

Alguna idea de como puedo hacerlo?? Muchas gracias

```
package com.example.usuario.coolmodapp.Lista;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.usuario.coolmodapp.R;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Usuario on 10/04/2017.
 */

public class PcAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PcAdapter.PcViewHolder> {

    private List<Pc> items;
    private Context mContext;

    public class PcViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // Campos respectivos de un item
        public TextView nombre;
        public TextView precio;
        public TextView descripcion;
        public ImageView imagen;
        public ImageView mas;

        public PcViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            nombre = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.nombre);
            precio = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.precio);
            descripcion = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.descripcion);
            imagen = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imagen);
        }
    }

    public PcAdapter(Context mContext, List<Pc> items)
    {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.items = items;

    }

    @Override
    public PcViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewTipe) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.cardview_layout, parent, false);
        return new PcViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final PcViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Pc pc = items.get(position);
        holder.nombre.setText(pc.getNombre());
        holder.precio.setText(pc.getPrecio());
        holder.descripcion.setText(pc.getDescripcion());
        holder.imagen.setImageResource(pc.getImagen());

        holder.imagen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showPopupMenu(holder.imagen);
            }
        });
    }

    private void showPopupMenu(View v)
    {
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(mContext, v);
        MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_pc, popup.getMenu());
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MyMenuItemClickListener());
        popup.show();
    }

    class MyMenuItemClickListener implements PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener{

        public MyMenuItemClickListener(){
        }
//Donde estan las 2 opciones del menu
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId())
            {
                case R.id.action_add:
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Añadir", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                case R.id.action_info:
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Mas informacion", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                default:
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: solo una peuqeña observación mas enficiente insertar el click en onCreateView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente lo he puesto asi y funciona

```
@Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            final Intent intent;
            switch (item.getItemId())
            {
                case R.id.action_add:
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Añadir", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.action_info:
                    mContext.startActivity(new Intent(mContext, Completo.class));
                    break;
                default:
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Entonces ya no es necesaria la linea final Intent intent; encima del switch

Comment: Sisi, copie el codigo sin borrar esa linea pero ya la tengo borrada

Answer (score 5):

Lo tienes casi hecho ya:

```
@Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                final Intent intent;
                switch (item.getItemId())
                {
                    case R.id.action_add:
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Añadir",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case R.id.action_info:
                        intent =  new Intent(mContext, TuActivityDestino.class);
                        break;
                    default:
                }
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }
```

Como ves es sencillo. Prueba y nos comentas.

Comment: Buenas, mas o menos esa es la idea que tenia pero no sabia exactamente como implementar el Intent, voy a probarlo gracias!

Comment: Cuando pongo el mContext.startActivity(intent), me sale que la Variable 'intent' might not have been initialized. Wtf? xD

Answer (score 3):

Para abrir una actividad desde otra se usa la función `startActivity(...)`

en tu caso al computar la opción del menú

```
mContext.startActivity(new Intent(mContext, OtraActividad.class));
```

Answer (score 2):

> Abrir una nueva pantalla, con un un onMenuItemClick y enviar datos.

**Para abrir una nueva Activity realizarías un intent** , en cuanto al **envio de datos, puedes agregar un `bundle` para enviar los datos**, para esto se tiene como ejemplo esta pregunta:

**[Pasar datos entre activities](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36902/pasar-datos-entre-activities/36924#36924)**

El cambio que realizarías sería definir un `Intent` para abrir la `Activity` deseada, de acuerdo a la opción seleccionada en el menú, y agregar datos para que sean recibidos en la `Activity` a abrir.

```
        @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                // * Define el Intent.
                final Intent intent = null;
                switch (item.getItemId())
                {
                    case R.id.action_add:
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Añadir",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        // * Define clase a abrir mediante Intent.
                        intent =  new Intent(mContext, OtraActivity1.class);
                        break;
                    case R.id.action_info:
                        // * Define clase a abrir mediante Intent.
                        intent =  new Intent(mContext, OtraActivity2.class);
                        break;
                    default:
                      // * Opción default clase a abrir mediante Intent.
                        intent =  new Intent(mContext, DefaultActivity.class);

                        break;
                }

               // * Agrega datos para enviar.
                intent.putExtra("usuario", "Cristian!");
                intent.putExtra("id", 123);
                intent.putExtra("latitud", 0.12324234);

                // * Inicia Activity
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }
```

Comment: Me pide que tengo que inicializar la variable Intent, porque sale ese error?

Comment: Solo inicializala de esta forma: final Intent intent = null; ya actualicè.

Answer (score 1):

Antes que nada, no es una buena prácitca crear el listener `onClick` en el `onBindViewHolder`:

Elimina esta linea de código de `onBindViewHolder`:

```
holder.imagen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showPopupMenu(holder.imagen);
            }
        });
```

Y agrega esta en el constructor de la clase `PcViewHolder`:

```
imagen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    showPopupMenu(imagen);
                }
            });
```

Si quieres iniciar un [DialogFragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html?hl=es) utiliza el siguiente código:

```
  FragmentManager fm = ((FragmentActivity)mContext).getSupportFragmentManager();
  YourDialog yourDialog = new YourDialog();
  yourDialog.show(fm, "YourDialog");
```

Si quieres iniciar una actividad:

```
Intent iActivity = new Intent(mContext, YourActivity.class);
mContext.startActivity(iActivity);
```

Comment: Yo siempre añado el listener click a OnCreateViewHolder sabes que diferencia está en hacerlo allí o como bien mencionas en el ViewHolder?

Comment: Hola @Webserveis, básicamente es lo mismo ya que devuelves la instancia de tu clase que implementa el Holder y pasas como parámetro la vista inflada, solo que tendrías que referenciar todos tus objetos en el onCreateViewHolder y no en la clase del Holder. Te recomiendo que hagas el set en la clase del Holder, siempre y cuando estés utilizando ViewHolders.