# Pasar parametros onClick de btn Android

Tags: android, android-intent

Tengo esta clase que carga un WebView con un constructor donde debo pasarle un String que es el enlace a la pagina.

```
public class amazonWeb extends AppCompatActivity {

String url;

public amazonWeb(String url){

    super();
    this.url = url;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_amazon_web);

    WebView webview = new WebView(this);
    setContentView(webview);
    webview.loadUrl(url);


}
}
```

Y lo llamo desde aqui. El problema es que no encuentro donde puedo pasarle el parametro :

```
    imgBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), amazonWeb.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes enviar en el Intent un bundle con datos, en este caso el url de la página web :

```
   imgBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), amazonWeb.class);
            intent.putExtra("url", "https://es.stackoverflow.com");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

y en la Activity que lo recibe lo tomas de los datos que recibe del Intent, **en este caso no veo necesario el constructor ya que no estas instanciando la `Activity` amazonWeb** :

```
public class amazonWeb extends AppCompatActivity {

String url;

/*public amazonWeb(String url){

    super();
    this.url = url;
}*/

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_amazon_web);

    url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");  //* Obtiene el valor de la url.

    WebView webview = new WebView(this);
    setContentView(webview);
    webview.loadUrl(url);


  }
}
```

Te recomiendo leer:

**[Pasar datos entre activities](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36902/pasar-datos-entre-activities/36924#36924)**