# Pasar nombre de usuario entre clases

Tags: java, android, variables

Necesito pasar el contenido del objeto que tiene el nombre de usuario entre difentes clases... 
Lo he intentado con un intent pero no me funciona

Clase de login usuario.

```
 public class Login extends AppCompatActivity implements  View.OnClickListener{

//URL hace referencia al fichero PHP subido en el servidor
public static final String REGISTER_URL = "http://appjerez.es/futpad/LoginUsuario.php";

public static final String KEY_NOMBRE = "nombre";
public static final String KEY_CONTRASEÑA = "password";
public EditText edLogin;
private EditText edPassword;
private Button btnLogin;
private Button btnCancelar;
private Button btnSalir;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    edLogin= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edLogin);
    edPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edPassword);
    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    btnCancelar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCancelar);
    btnSalir = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSalir);
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(this);

    //El botón Salir nos lleva al inicio de la aplicación.
    btnSalir.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Cuando pulsemos click en el botón realizara lo siguiente 

            Intent cancelar = new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(cancelar);
            //Cuando pulsemos Cancelar me mostrara un mensaje.
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Has pulsado Salir", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}

private void Login(){

    final String nombre = edLogin.getText().toString().trim();
    final String password = edPassword.getText().toString().trim();
    //Conexion con la base de datos mediante el fichero PHP alojado en el Hosting
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_URL,

            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    //La respuesta de este metodo onResponse si es cierto es "success"
                    if(response.trim().equals("success")){
                        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Bienvenido " + nombre, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent cancelar = new Intent(Login.this, MainDrawer.class);
                        startActivity(cancelar);
                        //Aqui pasamos el nombre de usuario a otra clase.
                        Intent login = new Intent(Login.this,MainDrawer.class);
                        // para enviar informacion entre Activity usamos
                        // el metodo putextra de las Intenciones
                        login.putExtra("Nombre",edLogin.getText().toString());
                        startActivity(login);
                    //Si la respuesta del método no es succes pues el usuario no existe.
                    //Entonces nos muestra mensaje de usuario no registrado.
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Usuario no registrado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        edLogin.getText().clear();
                        edPassword.getText().clear();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put(KEY_NOMBRE,nombre);
            params.put(KEY_CONTRASEÑA,password);
            return params;
        }
    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

//Metodo click en login
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
            Login();
  }
}
```

Clase donde quiero llevar el nombre de usuario:

```
    public class MainDrawer extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, PartidosFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
    RssFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener, ContactoFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
    InfoFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener, DesconectarFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
    InicioFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener{

private TextView txtBienvenido;
private ImageButton imageButtonAñadir;
private ImageButton imageButtonBuscar;
private ImageButton imageButtonSalir;
private ImageButton imgBtnMisPartidos;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_drawer);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //Muestra la bienvenida al usuario registrado
    txtBienvenido = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtLogear2);
    imageButtonAñadir = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonAñadir);
    imageButtonSalir = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonSalir);
    imageButtonBuscar = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonBuscar);
    imgBtnMisPartidos = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgBtnMisPartidos);

    //Muestra la bienvenida al usuario registrado
    txtBienvenido = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtLogear2);
    //Se extrae el nombre de usuario
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle extraEntreActividades = intent.getExtras();
    if (extraEntreActividades != null){
        String texto = extraEntreActividades.getString("Nombre");
        txtBienvenido.setText("Bienvenido: " + texto);

    }

    //Icono de menu despegable
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    //Boton para organizar partidos
    imageButtonAñadir.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent añadir = new Intent(MainDrawer.this, OrganizarPartidos.class);
            startActivity(añadir);
        }
    });

    //Boton para salir de la aplicacion
    imageButtonSalir.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainDrawer.this);
            builder.setMessage("¿Seguro que quieres salir de la aplicación?")
                    .setTitle("Atención!!")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancelar",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            })
                    .setPositiveButton("Aceptar",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                    Intent salir = new Intent(MainDrawer.this, MainActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(salir);
                                }
                            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }
    });

    //Boton para buscar partidos
    imageButtonBuscar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent buscar = new Intent(MainDrawer.this, BusquedaPartidos.class);
            startActivity(buscar);
        }
    });

    //Boton para ver mis partidos
    imgBtnMisPartidos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent buscar = new Intent(MainDrawer.this, MisPartidos.class);
            startActivity(buscar);
        }
    });

}

//Lo crea automicamente main drawer
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

//Lo crea automicamente main drawer
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_drawer, menu);
    return true;
}

//Lo crea automicamente main drawer
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

//Lo crea automicamente main drawer
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
//Menu para navegar por el menu despegable
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    //Declaramos id para interacion de los fragment
    int id = item.getItemId();

    Fragment fragment = null;
    //Creamos una variable para comprobar si hemos seleccionado el fragment.
    boolean FragmentSeleccionado = false;

    //En cada condicional IF, indicamos los ID que modificamos en "activity_main_drawer.xml"
    //Dentro de cada if indicamos lo que quiere hacer cuando pulsemos en la opcion del menú despegable

    if (id == R.id.nav_inicio) {
        fragment = new InicioFragment();
        FragmentSeleccionado = true;
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_partidos) {
        fragment = new PartidosFragment();
        FragmentSeleccionado = true;
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_rss) {
        fragment = new RssFragment();
        FragmentSeleccionado = true;
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_contacto) {
        fragment = new ContactoFragment();
        FragmentSeleccionado = true;
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_info) {
        fragment = new InfoFragment();
        FragmentSeleccionado = true;
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_desconectar) {
        fragment = new DesconectarFragment();
        FragmentSeleccionado = true;
    }

    //Con esta condicion IF indicamos que muestre el fragment seleccionado en el "content_main" pantalla inicial
    if(FragmentSeleccionado){
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, fragment).commit();
    }

    //Lo crea por defecto
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
    //Método obligatorio para los fragment, se deja vacio
    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

    }
}
```

Comment: que es ese mostrarusuario???

Comment: Se me olvido ponerlo mostrarusuario =  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), mostrarusuario, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: mmmm... no me cuadra esto que pones, para que te funcione tienes que poner Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getIntent().getExtras.getString("parametro"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); o Toast.makeText(this, getIntent().getExtras.getString("parametro"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: Javier estás llamando a 'mostrarusuario' dentro del Toast, tendrás que definirlo antes. ¿has hecho un por ejemplo un log de getIntent().getExtras().getString("parametro"); para ver en la consola si trae el valor o da error?

Comment: conseguí que funcione, con el 2 Toast me ha funcionado. El problema es que si cambio de activity y mas tarde vuelvo a BusquedaPartidos ya no aparece el Toast. Solo aparece la primera vez q se abre el activity BusquedaPartidos. Como podria hacerlo permanente?

Comment: Para tu última pregunta: Seguramente estás mostrando el `Toast` en el método `onCreate`, si no cierras la actividad, no se volverá a ejecutar dicho método. Para ello, sobreescribe el método `onResume`, dejo una imagen con el ciclo de vida de Android: https://www.javatpoint.com/images/androidimages/Android-Activity-Lifecycle.png

Comment: Lo siento amigo no funciona, haber es una especie de menu. La primera vez q entro en el activity si me funciona el Toast bien. Pero si cambio a otro activity y luego vuelvo al mismo ya el Toast no me muestra nada. Lo que necesito es que cada vez q entre en dicho activity me aparezca el Toast...

Answer (score 0):

Si vas a enviar datos entre Activities, lo realizas enviando los datos en el `bundle`

```
intent.putExtra("usuario", "Javier");
startActivity(intent);
```

y los recibes en la Activity destino mediante

```
String mostrarusuario = getIntent().getExtras().getString("usuario");
```

o simplemente:

```
String mostrarusuario = getIntent().getStringExtra("usuario");
```

Puedes ver más información en esta pregunta:

**[Pasar datos entre activities](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36902/pasar-datos-entre-activities)**

En cuando a que "regresas y ya no aparece el toast", debes saber en que parte lo estas llamando, si lo declaraste dentro de onCreate() y no se vuelve a reconstruir la activity es obvio que no se llamaría nuevamente.

---

Puedes definir una variable a nivel de clase

```
String mostrarusuario = "";
```

obtener en `onCreate()` el valor de esta variable:

```
mostrarusuario = getIntent().getStringExtra("usuario");
```

y muestra tu Toast con este valor cuando se muestra la `Activity`, por medio del método `onResume()`:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {

       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), mostrarusuario, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    super.onResume();
}
```

Comment: Lo siento amigo no funciona, haber es una especie de menu. La primera vez q entro en el activity si me funciona el Toast bien. Pero si cambio a otro activity y luego vuelvo al mismo ya el Toast no me muestra nada. Lo que necesito es que cada vez q entre en dicho activity me aparezca el Toast...

Comment: Te sugiero agregues tus clases completas para no estar adivinando hehe :D

Comment: He editado el comentario, ahora aparece el codigo de ambas clases.....