# Android: Login - Cómo pasar los datos de una activity a otra?

Tags: php, android, mysql, login, activity

Mi app venía bien hasta que me encontré con este problema.

Para ponerlos en contexto:
Estoy haciendo una app de Login en Android Studio para una página web. Este login se conecta con el php de la página y a su vez estos php se encargan de validar el usuario y contraseña.

Lo que tengo yo, son 3 activities: LoginActivity, BackgroundWorker y MenuActivity.

**LoginActivity** se encarga de capturar el usuario y contraseña y se los pasa al BackgroundWorker.

**BackgroundWorker** recibe el usuario y clave ingresados y se conecta a la url php de la página, el php los valida y devuelva una respuesta, si la respuesta es que tiene accesso se debería abrir *MenuActivity*, en teoría.

**MenuActivity** lo que hace es mostrar un webview en pantalla, desde una url php de la página con el *usuario* (por ejemplo: mipagina.com/menu+usuario.php).

Logré pasar el usuario y pass introducidos en LoginActivity a BackgroundWorker para que valide y devuelva una respuesta. Pero no puedo pasar el usuario de LoginActivity a MenuActivity. (Más o menos así me lo plantee yo)

LoginActivity.java
Les dejo los codigos para que vean.

```js
public void validarLogin(){
        if (txtUser.getText().toString().equals("") || txtPass.getText().toString().equals(""))
        {
            Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), "Faltan ingesar datos.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            String user = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtUser)).getText().toString();
            String password = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPassword)).getText().toString();
            String type = "login";
            
            
             miapp.BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new miapp.BackgroundWorker(this);
            backgroundWorker.execute(type, user, password);
        }
    }
```

BackgroundWorker.java

```js
public class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

    Context context;
    AlertDialog alertDialog;
    BackgroundWorker (Context ctx) {
        context = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String type = params[0];
        String user_name = params[1];
        String password = params[2];

        String login_url = "http://miweb.com.ar/app_usuario.php?pf=dame_tipo&p0="+user_name+"&p1="+password;


        if(type.equals("login")) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(login_url);

                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);

                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("user_name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(user_name,"UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(post_data);

                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();

                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
                String result="";
                String line="";

                while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null) {
                    result += line;
                }

                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();

                return result;


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Login Status");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        alertDialog.setMessage(result);
        //alertDialog.show();
        if (result.contains("E")) // E = No está registrado.
        {
            Toast.makeText(this.context, "No tiene permisos para acceder.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if (result.contains("C")) // C = Clave errónea.
        {
            Toast.makeText(this.context, "Contraseña incorrecta.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            if (result.contains("P")) // P = Tiene acceso.
            {
                Toast.makeText(this.context, "Accediendo a miWeb.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Intent intent = new Intent(this.context, MenuActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                this.context.startActivity(intent);
                //intent.putExtra("user_name", user_name);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
}
```

MenuActivity.java

```js
public class MenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

        if (bundle != null){
            String user = getIntent().getExtras().getString("user_name");

            String url = "http://miweb.com/app_usuario.php?pf=dame_clin&p0="+user;

            WebView view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webview);
            view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            view.loadUrl(url);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revisa como se envian datos entre Activities en esta respuesta:

[Pasar nombre de usuario entre clases](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/79773/pasar-nombre-de-usuario-entre-clases/79805#79805)

Si tienes los datos en `BackgroundWorker` puedes enviarlos en un bundle mediante el intent, para esto te sugiero primeramente, definas las variables a nivel de la clase:

```
public class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

    private String type = "";
    private String user_name = "";
    private String password = ";
    ...
    ...
```

y dentro de `doInBackground()` asigna el valor a las variables:

```
  @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        type = params[0];
        user_name = params[1];
        password = params[2];
    ...
    ...
```

al tener estos valores, puedes enviarlos a `MenuActivity` mediante un bundle:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this.context, MenuActivity.class);
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

 intent.putExtra("usuario", user_name);
 intent.putExtra("password", password); 

 this.context.startActivity(intent);
```

En `MenuActivity`  los obtienes de esta forma:

```
String usuario = getIntent().getStringExtra("usuario ");
String password = getIntent().getStringExtra("password");
```

Answer (score 0):

Para pasar datos entre activitys puedes usar los Bundles, he visto que en la clase MenuActivity.java obtienes un Bundle si existe, pero en la clase BackgroundWorker.java al llamar a MenuActivity no le metes el bundle como extra. Tienes comentado un intent.putExtra(); lo que tienes que hacer es crear un nuevo bundle algo como..

```
Bundle myBundle = new Bundle();
```

Y meterle los datos que quieras pasarle

```
myBundle.putString("key","value");
```

y finalmente añadir el bundle al intent y llamar al activity

```
intent.putExtras(myBundle);
startActivity(intent);
```