# SharedPreferences guardar datos al salir de la aplicación y volver a entrar?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-fragment, sharedpreferences

El problema es que el **SharedPreferences** no me muestra un dato que tengo guardado en él cuando salgo y vuelvo a entrar a la aplicación.

Las lineas de código en donde guardo el dato en los **SharedPreferences** esta dentro del `Activity` de un **Menú Lateral** y las lineas de código en donde acceso a ellos para mostrar el dato, se encuentra en un `Fragment`, específicamente en el **onCreateView()**.

**Activity "Menu_Lateral" :**

```
final Context context = this;
    final SharedPreferences sharedPre = getSharedPreferences("Mis_preferences", context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    String tipo_usuario = getIntent().getStringExtra("post");

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Menu Lateral :"+tipo_usuario, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    //Guardando el dato en SharedPreferences
    SharedPreferences sharpref = getPreferences(context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharpref.edit();
    editor.putString("type_user", tipo_usuario);
    editor.apply();
```

**Fragment "Contactos" :**

```
    SharedPreferences sharpref = getActivity().getPreferences(getActivity().MODE_PRIVATE);
    String valor = sharpref.getString("type_user","No hay dato");

    //Cada vez que inicio sesion, este Toast me muestra el dato supuestamente guardado correctamente, pero cuando salgo y vuelvo a entrar, el dato es "No hay dato"
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ""+valor, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: trata de reemplazar en el fragment contactos getActivity() por "Mis_preferences"

Comment: No, el problema ahora es que debo cambiar "getPreferences" a "getSharedPreferences" y el "getActivity" no lo puedo quitar ya que de ahi obtengo el "Context" que necesita el "SharedPreferences".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El primer problema es que no estas guardando correctamente los valores, si creas una SharedPreferences  con nombre "Mis_preferences", debes usar esta misma para guardar el valor:

```
final Context context = this;
    final SharedPreferences sharedPre = getSharedPreferences("Mis_preferences", context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    String tipo_usuario = getIntent().getStringExtra("post");

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Menu Lateral :"+tipo_usuario, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    //Guardando el dato en SharedPreferences
    //SharedPreferences sharpref = getPreferences(context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    //SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharpref.edit();
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPre.edit();
    editor.putString("type_user", tipo_usuario);
    editor.apply();
```

El segundo problema es que no estas definiendo el nombre de la preferencia que creas inicialmente, en este caso es `"Mis_preferences"`, por lo tanto no esta obteniendo los valores que guardas.

```
SharedPreferences sharpref = getActivity().getPreferences(getActivity().MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Para obtener los valores debes definir de que preferencia, además recuerda que debes usar `getSharedPreferences()` y no `getPreferences()`:

```
//SharedPreferences sharpref = getActivity().getPreferences(getActivity().MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences sharpref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Mis_preferences", getActivity().MODE_PRIVATE);
String valor = sharpref.getString("type_user","No hay dato");
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ""+valor, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Revisa esta pregunta:

[Guardar SharedPreferences asignandole una key](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/8559/guardar-sharedpreferences-asignandole-una-key?rq=1)

Comment: Listo Jorge, pero sigue el problema de que al salirme de la App y al volver a entrar no me muestra el dato, que estare haciendo mal? No mas para que lo sepas y no se si lo estoy haciendo mal, al iniciar sesion mi App realiza una consulta y devuelve un dato, ese lo envio al Menu Lateral en donde lo guardo, la aplicacion ya cuenta con sistema que guarda la sesion, asi que cuando vuelvo a entrar me manda directo al menu, pero eso no deberia ser problema ya que por eso al iniciar sesion por primera vez, se esta guardando en el preferences!!!

Comment: Checho, debe funcionar como esta, recuerda que la activity debe recibir el dato mediante un Intent, asegura enviarlo. Como prueba agrega fijo este valor en tu Activity y prueba String tipo_usuario = "Checho";

Comment: Si tienes razón, ya lo probé y si funciona el SharedPreferences, el problema esta en el dato. Gracias Jorge, ya puedo estar tranquilo que si funciona bien ahora debo solucionar lo otro.

Comment: Perfecto Checho, para enviar datos entre clases te sugiero veas: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/79773/pasar-nombre-de-usuario-entre-clases/79805#79805 saludos!

Comment: Solo era para avisarte que ya lo solucione :D, muchas gracias Jorge, saludos!!

Comment: excelente @ChechoParrado, saludos!