# Almacenar datos de forma temporal en android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estoy creado un carrito de compras en Android, el usuario tiene la opción de ver un producto en un ListView luego al darle clic se va a un activity donde ve el detalle de producto y tiene la opción de confirmar la compra, hasta aquí todo bien pero quiero dar la opcion de seguir comprando y hasta el final confirmar toda la compra, aquí es donde no se cual es la mejor opcion si guardar cada pedido de forma temporal el la BD o si hay otra forma de guardar temporalmente el pedido e ir agregando mas productos.
Habia pensado en crear un ArrayList pero cada vez que entro al activity detalle se reinicia dicho Array.

```
btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),codigo,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            pedido.add(codigo);
        }
    })
```

Comment: Lo mejor que puedes hacer es almacenar los artículos en la DB y a determinadas acciones(comprar, cancelar, vaciar carrito) vaciar la tabla. O bien, utlizar  almacenamiento de datos mediante **SharedPreferences**.

Comment: Revisa:[SharedPreferences guardar datos al salir de la aplicación y volver a entrar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/98895/sharedpreferences-no-me-muestra-dato-guardado-al-salir-de-la-aplicaci%C3%B3n-y-volver)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si es algo temporal talvez puedas utilizar las preferencias pero lo recomendado sería una base de datos.

Te dejare un ejemplo de las preferencias.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MisPreferencias",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

editor.putString("email", "modificado@email.com");

editor.putString("nombre", "Prueba");

editor.commit();
// hasta ahora has guardado un nombre y un email

String correo = prefs.getString("email", " texto por defecto");

String nombre = prefs.getString("nombre", " texto por defecto");
// asi obtienes lo que has guardado.
```

Nota: es muy util para guardar datos temporales e incluso utilizar valores en varios formularios o activitys. Pero no acepta datos complejos como objetos o arrays.

También puedes guardar lo que elija el usuario en preferencias y si acepta la compra lo guardas en una base de datos.
Solo debes sacarle el jugo a las preferencias, además estas también se pueden borrar por si el usuario elimina el pedido o lo cancela.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar cualquiera de las opciones de Almacenamiento:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage

Como ejemplo Shared preferences:

Crea una SharedPreferences  con nombre deseado por ejemplo "Mis_preferencias", debes usar esta misma para guardar el valor:

```
final Context context = this;
    final SharedPreferences sharedPre = getSharedPreferences("Mis_preferencias", context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    //Guardando el dato en SharedPreferences
    //SharedPreferences sharpref = getPreferences(context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    //SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharpref.edit();
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPre.edit();
    editor.putString("codigo", codigo);
    editor.apply();
```

Para obtener los valores debes definir de que preferencia, además recuerda que debes usar `getSharedPreferences()` :

```
//SharedPreferences sharpref = getActivity().getPreferences(getActivity().MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences sharpref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Mis_preferencias", getActivity().MODE_PRIVATE);
String codigo = sharpref.getString("codigo","No hay dato");
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), codigo, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Revisa esta pregunta:

[Guardar SharedPreferences asignandole una key mediante getDefaultSharedPreferences()](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/8559/guardar-sharedpreferences-asignandole-una-key-mediante-getdefaultsharedpreferenc?rq=1)