# Problema al mostrar notificación push en una nueva actividad

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, push-notification

1. El problema que tengo es que al pulsar sobre la notificación push recibida en la barra de estado, no se abre la actividad que he seleccionado para tal fin, se sigue abriendo la actividad principal si me pueden ayudar por favor revisar que sucede y que siempre se abra la actividad PushActivity.class.
2. Por otro lado, el objetivo es mostrar la notificación en un texView, bueno como no se abre la actividad no se está enviando, sin embargo agregué un listener solo para abrir esa actividad y ver si llega la notificación push y se coloca en el texView pero al parecer llega null.

Por favor agradezco la ayuda, a continuación los códigos.

**MyFirebaseMessagingService**

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

public String notificacion;

public static final String TAG = "NOTICIAS";

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {

    }
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        mostrarNotificacion(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(), remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

    }
}

private void mostrarNotificacion(String title, String body) {

    //Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PushActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(soundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());

    Log.d(TAG, "fari"+ body);
    notificacion = body;
    Intent i = new Intent(this, PushActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("ms", notificacion);
    startActivity(i);
}
}
```

La actividad que se debe abrir y que debe recibir los parametros del push notification en el textView es el siguiente:

**PushActivity**

```
public class PushActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "ivan";
public TextView tx_push;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_push);

    tx_push = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.push_id);

    String msm = getIntent().getExtras().getString("ms");
    tx_push.setText(msm);
    Log.d(TAG, "ivan"+ msm);

}
}
```

**Tengo este error**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Alfredo y que mensaje te muestra en el LogCat?

Comment: @Jorgesys disculpa, comenté la parte final en la PushActivity porque asi si me muestra el error, y yo creo que el primer problema es que no abre la PushActivity cuando abro la notificación.

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(this, PushActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

Comment: Antes abría esta activity pero cuando la empiezo a crear, una vez le agrego algo ya no vuelve a abrirse con la notificación.

Comment: ya quitandole la validacion de null en log cat veo este mensaje: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at com.tics.uniagustiniana.firebase.PushActivity.onCreate(PushActivity.java:20)

Comment: Estoy trabajando con esta respuesta https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/93777/34903

Comment: Veo varias cosas que no son correctas, lo que deseas es que al crar la notificación cuando se de click se abra la Activity y esta activity reciba el mensaje???

Comment: @Jorgesys Si ya voy a editar el código, en este momento si se abre la segunda actividad, pero como enviar el mensaje String a esa actividad no me funciona lo dejé comentariado, me puedes ayudar porfa a que llegue el mensaje a la otra actividad.

Comment: No necesitas realizar otro intent de hecho el método private void mostrarNotificacion(String title, String body) { es el único que necesitas, en el Intent defines que Activity abriras al dar clic en la notificación y ahí defines el texto que recibira la Activity @IvanAlfredo agrego respuesta!.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78196/discussion-between-ivan-alfredo-and-jorgesys).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo necesitas el método  `mostrarNotificacion()`, este método lo que realiza es crear una notificación, esta notificación lo que realiza es que al dar click se abra la Activity `PushActivity`:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, PushActivity.class);
```

si deseas agregar un mensaje debes definirlo en este Intent:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, PushActivity.class);
 intent.putExtra("ms", "Message by Jorgesys"); //* Valor a enviar!
```

No necesitas crear otro `Intent`, solo uno el cual se definirá en el `PendingIntent` para que al dar clic en la notificación abra la `Activity` definida en el `Intent`.

```
 private void mostrarNotificacion(String title, String body) {

        //Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        //Aqui intento seleccionar la actividad que se abre con el push
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PushActivity.class);

        intent.putExtra("ms", "Message by Jorgesys"); //* Valor a enviar!

        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(soundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());

    }
```

te sugiero validar también si no se reciben datos en el `bundle` en `PushActivity`:

```
if(getIntent().getExtras() != null){
    String msm = getIntent().getExtras().getString("ms");
    tx_push = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.push_id);
    tx_push.setText(msm);
    Log.d(TAG, "ivan"+ msm);
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, perfecto, el mensaje llega a la segunda actividad.

Comment: @IvanAlfredo excelente Alfredo! saludos!

Comment: Tengo una nueva pregunta relacionada a esta, me puedes ayudar por favor, https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/171477/34903