# Abrir actividad prevista para notificación push aunque la aplicación esté cerrada

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

El problema que tengo es que cuando la aplicación está cerrada, al pulsar sobre la notificación push, se abre la actividad principal (MainActivity) de la aplicación y no la actividad que tengo prevista para las notificaciones push, cuando la aplicación se encuentra abierta si se abre la actividad prevista en este caso (pushActivity).

En la clase MyFirebaseMessagingService recibe el mensaje, en el método mostrarNotificacion se abre la actividad PushActivity.

```
private void mostrarNotificacion(String title, String body) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PushActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("ms", body); //* Valor a enviar!
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    Log.d(TAG, "llegada: " + body);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(soundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());

}
```

Esta prueba la hago en el emulador y también en mi celular, en el emulador sucede lo que describo arriba, pero en el celular que tengo la app instalada desde playstore, nunca abre la actividad PushActivity sino que siempre muestra la actividad principal, nosé si sea posible que la vista quede abajo o algo así. las imágenes a continuación son tomadas del emulador, muestra la actividad y la notificación en el textView, solo cuando la app está abierta y en pantalla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.tics.uniagustiniana">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name=".firebase_messaging.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name=".firebase_messaging.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" />
    <activity android:name=".firebase_database.PollaMundialista" />
    <activity android:name=".firebase_messaging.PushActivity" />
</application>
```

Comment: Agrega tu Manifest.xml para saber como estan configuradas tus activities.

Comment: @Jorgesys ya lo agregué

Comment: Hola @Jorgesys has podido ver el manifest, encontraste algo..

Comment: Como sugerencia, si no encuentras solucion, podrias detectar desde tu app principal que si se trata de un acceso desde la notificacion push, entonces que redirija a la PushActivity. =)

Comment: Si ya he verificado que abre PushActivity en el emulador cuando la app esta en pantalla, recibe el texto y lo muestra, pero por lo general no abre esta actividad sino que abre MainActivity :(

Comment: @IvanAlfredo en que sistema operativo estas probando, te lo comento porque he probado lo que tienes y funciona sin problema en 7.0 y 7.1 el OS podría ser una razón.

Comment: El amulador es API 21 y solo en mi celular lo tengo instalado para pruebas con Android 7.0

Comment: Ya he probado en otras versiones instalé nuevos emuladores y me sucede lo mismo, solo abre  PushActivity cuando la app esta en pantalla.

Comment: Quizás esto te ayude
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/171477/abrir-actividad-prevista-para-notificaci%C3%B3n-push-aunque-la-aplicaci%C3%B3n-est%C3%A9-cerrad

Answer (score 3):

Para que se entienda

- Cuando la app esta en segundo plano las notificaciones que llegan pasan a la bandeja del sistema. Cuando un usuario las toca abre la aplicacion.
- Esto incluye mensajes que contienen notificaciones y carga de datos (payloads). En estos casos, la notificación se entrega a la bandeja del sistema del dispositivo, y la carga útil de datos (payload) se entrega en los extras de la actividad de su iniciador.

Ahora, de acuerdo a la [documentacion](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options) de FCM hay una unica opcion para abrir una activity al mandar una notificacion.

Esta forma es distinta a la que estamos acostumbrados mandando mensajes push normalmente.

Para que esto funciones debemos pasarle a nuestra notificacion unas "cargas extras" (los famosos payloads) dentro de ellos para que luego al apretarla y pasarla a los extras de nuestra app podamos de esa forma obtener esa informacion y hacer algo dentro de la app.

Esta carga especifica que necesitamos es el famoso `click_action` dentro de nuestra notificación.

De acuerdo a la documentacion oficial:

- Configura las claves apropiadas para determinar la acción que se realizará cuando un usuario presione la notificación en Android y en iOS (`click_action` y `category`, respectivamente).

brindando el siguiente hint de una estructura json de como seria el mensaje

```
{
  "message":{
     "token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
     "notification":{
       "title":"Match update",
       "body":"Arsenal goal in added time, score is now 3-0"
     },
     "android":{
       "ttl":"86400s",
       "notification"{
         "click_action":"OPEN_ACTIVITY_1"
       }
     },
     "apns": {
       "headers": {
         "apns-priority": "5",
       },
       "payload": {
         "aps": {
           "category": "NEW_MESSAGE_CATEGORY"
         }
       }
     },
     "webpush":{
       "headers":{
         "TTL":"86400"
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

Descomponiendo un poco esta estructura podemos encontrar algunas cosas interesantes que estamos mandando como notificacion

primero el titulo y el cuerpo de la misma se definen al principio

```
"message":{
         "token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
         "notification":{
           "title":"Match update",
           "body":"Arsenal goal in added time, score is now 3-0"
         },
```

Aca podemos ver el token (identificador unico) de la notificacion, su titulo y su mensaje el cual mostraran cuando llegue a nuestro dispositivo

Ahora , lo siguiente vendria siendo nuestro payload o informacion extra que le mandamos, con el fin de poder agarrarla y realizar alguna accion dentro de nuestra app

```
 "android":{
           "ttl":"86400s",
           "notification"{
             "click_action":"OPEN_ACTIVITY_1"
           }
         },
         "apns": {
           "headers": {
             "apns-priority": "5",
           },
           "payload": {
             "aps": {
               "category": "NEW_MESSAGE_CATEGORY"
             }
           }
```

Como vemos, podemos ver que pasamos algo muy peculiar `"click_action":"OPEN_ACTIVITY_1"`  esta accion que detallamos como parte de nuestro mensaje es lo que vamos a decodificar cuando el usuario aprete nuestra notificacion. Cuando aprete le vamos a decir que abra la activity `"OPEN_ACTIVITY_1"` que podria ser cualquiera.

Bien, pero ahora la pregunta... ¿ Como realizo esto con Firebase Console ?

Bueno, para aproximarnos al final de la pregunta podemos mandar ese click_action dentro de nuestra notificacion.

Ahora, ¿ Como hago que mi app reciba esta informacion y de alguna manera me abra mi activity ?

Bueno, lo que vamos a hacer es simple, vamos a dejar que nuestra app al apretarla nos lleve a la actividad principal o Launcher definida por nuestro Manifest, y dentro de ella vamos a tener un `getExtras` que va a obtener los datos de esta notificacion y asi ir hacia la proxima actividad.

Primero vamos a crear un Helper que nos va a ayudar cuando cliquemos nuestra notificacion, tomando los datos de la misma

```
public class ClickActionHelper {
    public static void startActivity(String className, Bundle extras, Context context){
        Class cls;
        try {
            cls = Class.forName(className);
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
            //means you made a wrong input in firebase console
        }
        Intent i = new Intent(context, cls);
        i.putExtras(extras);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

AHORA, MUY IMPORTANTE !

en tu MainActivity, o a la activity donde va la notificaion por defecto , en tu `onCreate()` vas a chequear si dentro de la notificacion tenemos un `click_action` o no, para abrir asi una nueva actividad.

entonces, dentro de nuestro `onCreate()`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    [...]
    checkIntent(getIntent());
 }
```

Tambien podemos llamar a checkIntent en `onNewIntent()`  que solo se llama en lugar de `onCreate()` si la actividad se inicia con un indicador de una sola cima top-flag

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    [...]
    checkIntent(intent);
}
```

y al final nuestro metodo checkIntent() que va a chequear estos datos

```
public void checkIntent(Intent intent) {
       if (intent.hasExtra("click_action")) {
        ClickActionHelper.startActivity(intent.getStringExtra("click_action"), intent.getExtras(), this);
       }
}
```

Ahora por ultimo solo queda iniciar nuestra activity en `onMessageReceived()`

```
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
     Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();        
     if (data.containsKey("click_action")) {
         ClickActionHelper.startActivity(data.get("click_action"), null, this);
     }
 }
```

y ahora MUY IMPORTANTE es mandar bien nuestra notificacion desde la consola

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esto lo puedes abrir en configuracion avanzada dentro de cloud messaging en firebase, o por donde mandas la notificacion

Es algo largo de entender pero trate de detallarlo al maximo, espero les sirva !

Comment: estaria bueno saber para el que dio -1, el por que, ya que me esmere bastante en dar una resolucion completa del problema

Comment: Suele pasar que la gente vote negativo sin sentido alguno , gran respuesta

Comment: muchas gracias.

Comment: Yo no vote  a esta respuesta, pero te comento que esto no da solución ya que precisamente startActivity() no esta abriendo la Actividad que desea, yo probé la configuración que tiene Ivan en su pregunta y me funciona sin problema, el problema es alguna configuración extraña.

Comment: antes lo solia hacer asi pero sin la consola, llamaba al endpoint y mandaba el mensaje por post

Comment: @Gastón muchas muchas gracias, estuve un tiempo ausente de la plataforma estoy de regreso para seguir con la app...

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, PushActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("ms", 1); //* Valor a enviar!
```

....

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {


  int ms = getIntent().getExtras().getString("ms");
  if(ms == 1){
    startActivity(new Intent(this, PushActivity.class). // Abre nueva Activity.
    finish(); //Cierra Activity principal.
  }

    // clean intent for new Push Notification Data.
    super.onNewIntent(null);
}
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu respuesta de mejor manera. También puedes revisar [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Saludos.

Comment: Andrés debe de ser una solución más elegante, imagina que este abierta la aplicación, si abre la notificación le cerrara la aplicación (MainActivity).

Comment: En ese intent envío el mensaje de la notificación push entonces no me queda claro porque se cambia por un 1.

Comment: Lo usé de ejemplo ya que no sabía qué contenía body