# Abrir un fragment desde otro fragment de diferente activity

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-viewpager

Tengo una duda 
En este código que tengo actualmente, ubicado en un fragment contiene un "swich case" que abre un activity diferente, ahora lo que hice es crear otro un activity 2 el cual carga 12 fragments con un viewPager, que remplazaría a estas 12 activities
¿Alguien Sabe como hacerle para que en cada "case" habra un fragment en especifico del activity 2

ESTE ES EL FRAGMENT DONDE CONTIENE LOS ENLACES

```
public class ElRecorridoFragment extends Fragment {
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

RecyclerView recyclerEstaciones;
ArrayList<EstacionesVo> listaEstaciones;

public ElRecorridoFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}



public static ElRecorridoFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    ElRecorridoFragment fragment = new ElRecorridoFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }



}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View vista = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_el_recorrido, container, false);

    listaEstaciones = new ArrayList<>();



    recyclerEstaciones = vista.findViewById(R.id.RecyclerRecorridoId);
    recyclerEstaciones.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

    llenarLista();

    AdaptadorEstaciones adapter = new AdaptadorEstaciones(listaEstaciones);

    adapter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            switch (recyclerEstaciones.getChildAdapterPosition(view)){

                case 0: Intent est1 = new Intent (getActivity(), Estaciones.class);
                    startActivity(est1);
                    break;


                case 1: Intent est2 = new Intent (getActivity(), Estacion02.class);
                    startActivity(est2);
                    break;
                case 2: Intent est3 = new Intent (getActivity(), MapsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(est3);
                    break;
                case 3: Intent est4 = new Intent (getActivity(), Estaciones.class);
                    startActivity(est4);
                    break;
                case 4: Intent est5 = new Intent (getActivity(), Estacion05.class);
                    startActivity(est5);
                    break;
                case 5: Intent est6 = new Intent (getActivity(), Estacion06.class);
                    startActivity(est6);
                    break;
                case 6: Intent est7 = new Intent (getActivity(), Estacion07.class);
                    startActivity(est7);
                    break;
                case 7: Intent est8 = new Intent (getActivity(), Estacion08.class);
                    startActivity(est8);
                    break;
                case 8: Intent est9 = new Intent (getActivity(), Estacion09.class);
                    startActivity(est9);
                    break;
                case 9: Intent est10 = new Intent (getActivity(), Estacion10.class);
                    startActivity(est10);
                    break;
                case 10: Intent est11 = new Intent (getActivity(), Estacion11.class);
                    startActivity(est11);
                    break;
                case 11: Intent est12 = new Intent (getActivity(), Estacion12.class);
                    startActivity(est12);
                    break;

            }

            //  Toast.makeText(getContext(), "haz hecho click en: " +listaEstaciones.get(recyclerEstaciones.getChildAdapterPosition(view)).getNombre(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });


    recyclerEstaciones.setAdapter(adapter);

    return vista;
}

private void llenarLista() {

    listaEstaciones.add(new EstacionesVo(getString(R.string.Estacion_1_Titulo), R.drawable.estacion01));
    listaEstaciones.add(new EstacionesVo(getString(R.string.Estacion_2_Titulo), R.drawable.estacion02));
    ETC........
    listaEstaciones.add(new EstacionesVo(getString(R.string.Estacion_12_Titulo), R.drawable.estacion12));

}

// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
}
```

ESTE EL EL SEGUNDO ACTIVITY DONDE SE CARGAN LOS 12 FRAGMENTS

```
     public class Estaciones extends AppCompatActivity implements
        EstacionF_1.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        EstacionF_2.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        EstacionF_3.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        EstacionF_4.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        EstacionF_5.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        EstacionF_6.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        EstacionF_7.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        EstacionF_8.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        EstacionF_9.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        EstacionF_10.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        EstacionF_11.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        EstacionF_12.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_estaciones);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_Estaciones_ID);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));


    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager =(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.view_pager_est_Id);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);



}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_estaciones_2, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

/*    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }*/

    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.home_Id_2) {
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));
        return true;
    }


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

}

public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }


    public static Fragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {

        Fragment fragment = null;

        switch (sectionNumber){
            case 1: fragment = new EstacionF_1();
                break;
            case 2: fragment = new EstacionF_2();
                break;
            case 3: fragment = new EstacionF_3();
                break;
            case 4: fragment = new EstacionF_4();
                break;
            case 5: fragment = new EstacionF_5();
                break;
            case 6: fragment = new EstacionF_6();
                break;
            case 7: fragment = new EstacionF_7();
                break;
            case 8: fragment = new EstacionF_8();
                break;
            case 9: fragment = new EstacionF_9();
                break;
            case 10: fragment = new EstacionF_10();
                break;
            case 11: fragment = new EstacionF_11();
                break;
            case 12: fragment = new EstacionF_12();
                break;

        }

        return fragment;
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return rootView;
    }
}


public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // 12 paginas a mostrar
        return 12;
    }

}

public void setViewPager (int fragmentNumber)
{
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(fragmentNumber);
}

}
```

Y ESTE ES EL PRIMER FRAGMENT DE 12

```
public class EstacionF_1 extends Fragment {


private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public EstacionF_1() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}



public static EstacionF_1 newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    EstacionF_1 fragment = new EstacionF_1();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_estacion_f_1, container, false);
}

public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}


public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}

}
```

Espero y me puedan ayudar. Saludos a todos

Answer (score -1):

Es buena solución la que realizas, en lugar de varias Activities tener una sola Activity con un FragmentPagerAdapter que contiene los Fragments que representarian varias Activities.

Si tienes cargados los fragments en el viewPager y deseas abrir uno especifico, puedes usar el método [setCurrentItem()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setCurrentItem(int)), en el cual defines el indice del elemento en el viewPager que deseas visualizar.

Por ejemplo si deseas visualizar el tercer Fragment:

```
mViewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
```

Para definir que Fragment se mostraría antes de cargar la Activity que contiene los Fragments puedes [enviar ese dato mediante un bundle al cargar la Activity](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36902/pasar-datos-entre-activities/36924#36924)

```
intent.putExtra("indiceFragment", 2);   
startActivity(intent);
```

Recibes el dato en la Activity que contiene los Fragments y mueves el pager al Fragmento deseado dentro del viewPager.

```
Bundle datos = this.getIntent().getExtras();  
int indiceFragment = datos.getInt("indiceFragment");
mViewPager.setCurrentItem(indiceFragment);
```

Comment: -1? Alguna explicación?