# Como pasar un parámetro en una otra activity con un ALERT DIALOG?

Tags: android

Como puedo pasar un parámetro de un  input del AlertDialog en una otra activity? Cuando abre el AlertDialog , el usuario debe ingresar una cantidad , y esa cantidad lo quiero pasar a una otra activity..intente este código pero nunca me llego el input digitado del usuario en la secunda actividad... este es mi código

```
 final AlertDialog.Builder inputAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            inputAlert.setTitle("Compras");
            inputAlert.setMessage("Ingrese la cantidad deseado.");
            final EditText userInput = new EditText(context);
            inputAlert.setView(userInput);

             userInputValue = userInput.getText().toString();

            inputAlert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(Consart.this,Compra.class);
                    intent1.putExtra("TECLADO",userInputValue);


                    Log.i("NEW RESP", String.valueOf(userInput));

                        //  startActivity(intent2);
                        Toast.makeText(Consart.this, "Agregado...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

            });
            inputAlert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alertDialog = inputAlert.create();
            alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17226357/pass-the-user-input-from-an-alert-dialog-to-the-activity-and-process-it-once-the Espero te funcione, si lo logras, me avisas, y vemos la forma de hacerlo

Comment: Hola user62207,  bienvenido al sitio!, el código tiene lo necesario para funcionar, ¿Cual es el problema por que mencionas no funciono? ¿Como recibes los parametros en la Activity a donde deseas enviarlos?, te invito a realizar el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! para que obtengas buenas respuestas, para esto te sugiero leer [ask], saludos!

Answer (score 1):

En realidad primeramente revisa la forma de envíar datos entre Activities:

[Pasar datos entre activities](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36902/pasar-datos-entre-activities/36924#36924)

Uno de los errores es que **no estas definiendo el iniciar la otra Activity, mediante `startActivity()`**,

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(Consart.this,Compra.class);
intent1.putExtra("TECLADO",userInputValue);
startActivity(intent1); //*corregido
```

el segundo error es que al iniciar defines el valor de `userInputValue` pero este valor es "" ya que no cambia, **debes obtener el valor del `EditText` al generar el Dialogo y dar click en el botón "OK" del diálogo mediante `userInput.getText().toString()`**:

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(Consart.this,Compra.class);
intent1.putExtra("TECLADO", userInput.getText().toString()); //*corregido
startActivity(intent1);
```

teniendo esto, puedes enviar abrir la Activity al dar click en el botón "OK" del dialog y puedes recibir el valor de esta forma en tu segunda Activity:

```
String valorRecibido = bundle.getStringExtra("TECLADO");
```

---

El código corregido sería:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder inputAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            inputAlert.setTitle("Compras");
            inputAlert.setMessage("Ingrese la cantidad deseado.");
            final EditText userInput = new EditText(context);
            inputAlert.setView(userInput);

             userInputValue = userInput.getText().toString();

            inputAlert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(Consart.this,Compra.class);
                    intent1.putExtra("TECLADO", userInput.getText().toString()); //*corregido
                    startActivity(intent); //*corregido

                    Log.i("NEW RESP", String.valueOf(userInput));

                        //  startActivity(intent2);
                        Toast.makeText(Consart.this, "Agregado...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

            });
            inputAlert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alertDialog = inputAlert.create();
            alertDialog.show();
```