# Android Studio - Obtener valor de un EditText de otro Activity

Tags: android, layout, edittext

tengo un problema , cuando quiero referenciar en mi activity principal un valor de un objeto de otro activity , me devuelve nulo a pesar de que he utilizado inflater. este es mi codigo :

```
       LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item ,null);
        final EditText et1 = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.et1);
 String valor = et1.getText().toString();
```

Cuando muestro la variable valor, me devuelve nulo a pesar de que en el emulador ingreso el dato.

Comment: El valor lo quieres obtener cuando abres el otro activity o cuando lo cierras?

Comment: Hola EdU17 , bienvenido al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento 

básico del sitio y obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con 

respecto a tu pregunta debes modificarla para que cumpla con la calidad requerida en el sitio, 

esto para que pueda ser bien recibida por la comunidad y obtengas buenas respuestas, para esto 

**es muy importante leer [ask]**, saludos!

Answer (score -1):

Estas definiendo el valor de la variable `valor` cuando se construye la UI, en este punto el valor es null,

```
 final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item ,null);
 final EditText et1 = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.et1);
 String valor = et1.getText().toString();
```

**En realidad no puedes obtener el valor del EditText definido en otra Activity** obteniendo la referencia mediante `findViewById(R.id.et1)`, para eso puedes enviar el valor de tu `EditText` mediante un bundle.

Si deseas enviar el valor de un `EditText` desde otro Activity realizalo mediante el Intent:

[Pasar datos entre activities](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36902/pasar-datos-entre-activities/36924#36924)

por ejemplo:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(;MainActivity.this, SegundaActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("valor_edittext", editext.getText().ToString());
startActivity(intent);
```

al recibirlo en tu Segunda Activity simplemente lee el valor de esta forma:

```
  //Obtiene valor!
  String valorRecibido = bundle.getStringExtra("valor_edittext");

  final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item ,null);
  final EditText et1 = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.et1);

  et1.setText(valorRecibido); //asigna valor a EditText.
```