# Pasar valores de un activity(radiobutton) a otro activity

Tags: android-studio, radiobutton

Buenas, tengo un problema quiero pasar los datos de un `radiobutton` que están en dos activitys, uno se llama `sumaActivity` y el otro `restaActivity` diferentes a otro activity que se llama `resultadoActivity`

**sumaActivity**

```
  public class sumaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView txtpregunta;
    RadioButton rbtna,rbtnb,rbtnc,rbtnd;
    Button btnatras,btnsiguiente;
    RadioGroup rdgroup;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_suma);

        rdgroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rdgroup);
        txtpregunta = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtpregunta);
        rbtna = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbtna);
        rbtnb = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbtnb);
        rbtnc = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbtnc);
        rbtnd = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbtnd);
        btnatras= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnatras);
        btnsiguiente= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsiguiente);

        btnsiguiente.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),restaActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        rdgroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, @IdRes int checkedId) {
                if (checkedId == R.id.rbtna){

                }else if (checkedId == R.id.rbtnb){

                }else if (checkedId == R.id.rbtnc){

                }else if (checkedId == R.id.rbtnd){

                }
            }
        });
    }
```

**restaActivity**

```
  public class restaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView txtpregunta;
    RadioButton rbtna,rbtnb,rbtnc,rbtnd;
    Button btnatras,btnsiguiente;
    RadioGroup rdgroup;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_resta);

        rdgroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rdgroup);
        btnsiguiente = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsiguiente);

        btnsiguiente.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ResultadoActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        rdgroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, @IdRes int checkedId) {
                if (checkedId == R.id.rbtna){

                }else if (checkedId == R.id.rbtnb){

                }else if (checkedId == R.id.rbtnc){

                }else if (checkedId == R.id.rbtnd){

                }
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Y mi `resultadoActivity` que esta vació,
lo que quiero es que al momento de seleccionar una opcion del `radiobutton` de `sumaActivity` y una opcion del `radiobutton` de `restaActivity` se muestre en `resultadoActivity` lo que ha seleccionado

Comment: Esto es un duplicado de Enviar datos entre activities  : https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36902/enviar-datos-entre-activities/36924#36924

Answer (score 1):

**Para actividad sumar o restar es el mismo procedimiento**

*Así enviamos los datos*

```
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
    String str; // variable donde se almacenara el dato del radioButton

       switch(view.getId()) {
                    case R.id.radioButton1:
                        if (checked)
                         str = "button1Text";
                            break;
                    case R.id.radioButton2:
                        if (checked) str = "button2Text";
                            break;
                    case R.id.radioButton3:
                        if (checked) str = "button3Text";
                            break;
             }
  } 


            Intent intent = new Intent(this, resultadoActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("radioChosen", str); // enviaras lo que contiene str a la siguiente Activity
```

*Y para recibir en la actividad resultado el contenido de str:*

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String message= extras.getString("radioChosen");// radioChosen es el ID que le dimos a str. 

}
```

Comment: de donde sacas el view?

Comment: Respuesta editada @kevvelas

Comment: y de donde sacas el checked?

Comment: Eso es parte del radioButton en si @kevvelas