# como puedo enviar dos variables o parámetros a través de dos activitys en android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

este es parte de mi codigo lo que necesito es enviar el porcentaje junto con la matricula del alumno a una nueva la siguiente activity pero noce como alguien me pudiera orientar de como hacerlo
**int Porcentaje=2;
    String matricula;**
    MediaPlayer mp;

```
TextView tvdesierto, tvcoral, tvbosque;

final Context context = this;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gbloque2_tema1);

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    matricula = bundle.getString("matricula");
```

public  void feliz (View view)
    {
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ninoscelebrando);
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(GBloque2Tema1.this);

```
    View subView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feliz, null);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

    mp.start();
    builder
            .setView(subView)
            .setTitle("Respuesta Correcta")
            .setMessage("FELICIDADES!!")
            .setPositiveButton("Siguiente Adivinanza", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(GBloque2Tema1.this,GBloque2Tema1Desierto.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                    actulizardatos();
                }
            })
            .setCancelable(false)
            .show();
}

public void actulizardatos()
{
    MyDBHandler admin= new MyDBHandler(this,"MYDBHandler",null,1);
    SQLiteDatabase db= admin.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues registro= new ContentValues();
    registro.put("porcentaje", Porcentaje );
    db.update("AltaBloque2", registro, "matricula = ? and idmateria=1", new String[] {matricula});
}
```

Comment: Hola ALDAIR MOYORIDO, bienvenido a Stack Overflow, te sugiero revisar la sección de [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), para que tu preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Comment: Puedes agregar mas detalles a la pregunta? Cual es el código que haz probado? Tienes algún error?, etc.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Enviar datos entre activities](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36902/enviar-datos-entre-activities)

Comment: Aldair Moyorido, primeramente debes realizar preguntas basadas en el documento  [ask], es importante!. También puedes realizar una búsqueda en el sitio, puede ser que la información requerida ya se encuentré en el sitio como en este caso, revisa el enlace que te proporciona A.Cedano