# Error al pasar una variable de una Activity a un fragment

Tags: android

Cuando paso una variable desde la actividad del navigation drawer a un fragment, me da un error de null al recuperar esa variable. Voy a poner solo el código necesario. Esta actividad recibe variables del main y las pone en un bundle para enviarlas al fragment. Este es el onCreate de la actividad Navigation Drawer:

```
    public class NavigationDrawerActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, InicioFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener, PerfilFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    Alumno alum;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation_drawer);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
        Fragment fragment = new InicioFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.content_drawer, fragment).commit();

        String tipo = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Tipo");
        Fragment perfil = new PerfilFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

        alum = (Alumno) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("User");

        try {
            Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(alum.getFoto_perfil()).error(R.drawable.user).into(miImageViewDrawerFoto);
        }catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
            miImageViewDrawerFoto.setImageResource(R.drawable.user);
        }

        bundle.putSerializable("User", alum);
        bundle.putString("Tipo", tipo);

        perfil.setArguments(bundle);
    }
}
```

Y este es el método onCreate del fragment donde recupero la variable. El error de null me da en la linea de String tipo = getArguments().getString("Tipo");

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        tipo = getArguments().getString("Tipo");
    }
```

Gracias.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.example.pepe.proy.Fragments.PerfilFragment">    
<TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/dni"
                style="@style/LabelsMedium"
                />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Agrega tu layout para una respuesta más especifica, debes tener un FrameLayout para realizar la transaccion del Fragment. @PacoPepe

Answer (score 2):

Si deseas enviar un dato hacia un `Fragment` no necesitas iniciar una `Activity` mediante :

```
startActivity(i);
```

Esto se realiza para enviar datos entre Actividades:

[Enviar datos entre activities](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36902/enviar-datos-entre-activities)

Lo que debes realizar es una transacción del `Fragment`, agrega a tu `FrameLayout` un id `contenedor`:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.example.pepe.proy.Fragments.PerfilFragment"
    android:id="@+id/contenedor">
```

y este sería el código:

```
        String tipo = "Alumno";
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NavigationDrawerActivity.class);
        PerfilFragment perfiles = new PerfilFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("Tipo", tipo);                  
        perfiles.setArguments(bundle);    
        startActivity(i);

        //Realiza la transacción del Fragment
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.contenedor, perfiles);
        ft.commit();
```

Comment: El `FrameLayout` donde va a cargar el `Fragment` debe ser parte del layout que carga la Actividad. Tienes varios errores: 1. Estas iniciando una Actividad sobre el `Fragment` que se va agregar, esto hará que la Actividad se superponga a la actividad que maneja el `Fragment`. 2. Estas asignando el id contenedor al layout del `Fragment` que se va a cargar y no al contenedor del `Activity`.

Comment: He escrito el código de jorgesys y ahora me da error nada más cambiar de activity. No entiendo nada.

Comment: He añadido más código y he cambiado la info de la pregunta para facilitar la comprensión de mi problema. Apenas entiendo cómo funciona esto en Android.

Comment: Ya lo he arreglado. Solo tenía que poner el código de jorge en el switch que cambia de fragment en el NavigationDrawerActivity. Gracias a todos.

Answer (score 2):

Debes leer la documentacion oficial sobre los [Fragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments?hl=ES) para que tengas una idea de como funcionan. A diferencia de las [Activity](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities?hl=es-419) que se inician con [Intent](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters?hl=ES), los [Fragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments?hl=ES) deber ser creados con [Transacciones](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction?hl=ES) y dichas transacciones deben ser manejadas para definir el comportamiento del mismo.

Un ejemplo de como se debe agregar un [Fragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments?hl=ES) a un contenedor es la siguiente (este código debe ir en `MainActivity` que es donde defines el contenedor para el Fragment):

```
string tipo = "Alumno";
string tag = "Perfil";

PerfilFragment perfil = new PerfilFragment();
Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
arguments.putString("Tipo", tipo);
perfil.setArguments(arguments);
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
ft.add(R.id.fragment, perfil, tag);
ft.commit();
```

Ten en cuenta que `R.id.fragment` debe ser el id la vista que va a contener al [Fragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments?hl=ES), lo mas recomendable es un `FrameLayout` ligad a la [Actividad](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities?hl=es-419). Es decir que debe estar en el Layout que carga la [Actividad](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities?hl=es-419).

En tu caso por ejemplo, si el layout de tu `MainActivity` se llama: `activity_main.axml`, es decir en el `OnCreate` hiciste `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` debes agregar lo siguiente a tu `axml`:

```
. . .

<FrameLayout 
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>  

. . .
```

Mi recomendacion es que te leas las documentaciones para que entiendas como funcionan y cual es la diferencia:

- [Fragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments?hl=ES)
- [Transacciones](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction?hl=ES)
- [Activity](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities?hl=es-419)
- [Intent](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters?hl=ES)