# Android getActivity() devuelve null en Fragment

Tags: android, fragment

En una app con menú lateral, cuando hago click en uno de sus items, quiero cargar lo mismo que haciendo click en otro botón (también en un fragmento) de la aplicación. Para ello creo un objeto de esa clase y llamo a su método correspondiente desde onNavigationItemSelected(), pero al entrar en el método, se para en:

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
```

con el siguiente mensaje de error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.app.Activity.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

Así hago la llamada al método

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {        
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.miInstalaciones) {
        MainMenu_fragment mainMenu_fragment = new MainMenu_fragment();
        mainMenu_fragment.getTiposInstalacion();
```

Comment: Agrega en que parte estas llamando la linea que produce error.

Comment: Todavía continuas con el problema o lograste resolverlo?

Comment: Gracias por vuestra respuesta, conseguí solucionarlo con la respues de @Andrespengineer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que no debes llamar un método en la instancia de un `Fragment` que involucre a la `Actividad`, sin antes definir el ciclo de vida del `Fragment`. Tu código solo funcionaria si el `Fragment` ha sido inicializado, de manera que ya tenga su ciclo de vida funcional.

Para poder definir el ciclo de vida de un `Fragment`, debes iniciarlo con una transaccion y agregarlo al contenedor de la actividad.

Puedes ver un ejemplo en esta [Respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/163337/38154) que hice hace varios días. Luego de que hayas agregado e inicializado el Fragment de manera correcta, puedes llamar al método, en ese ejemplo, después de hacer commit.

Otra alternativa es la siguiente, similar a la [Respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/163337/38154):

```
MainMenu_fragment menuFragment = new MainMenu_fragment();
Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
arguments.putBoolean("InvocarMetodo", true);
menuFragment.setArguments(arguments);
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
ft.add(R.id.fragment, menuFragment, "Menu");
ft.commit();
```

Y obtener el valor en el onCreate del Fragment:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     if(getArguments() != null && getArguments().getBoolean("InvocarMetodo", false))
        getTiposInstalacion();
}
```

Ten en cuenta que estas agregando un `Fragment` al contenedor, no reemplazandolo, por si a caso. Si quieres resumir y pausar el que ya, reemplazarlo, etc... esta hay otras alternativas en la documentacion de las transacciones.

**PD:** si solo utilizas el codigo de `onNavigationItemSelected` para instanciar el Fragment, entonces deberias identificar el Fragment despues del commit e invocar el metodo despues de ahi. Ya que `getActivity()` siempre llegara null si la transaccion aun no se ha realizado.

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciona!