# Fragment setContentView Android

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, android-fragment

Hola buen día el día de hoy estaba haciendo una app conectada con Firebase a una base de datos la aplicacion ya hace la conexion y todo con unos tutoriales que vi en Youtube, pero ahora quería hacer más estética mi app y le agregué un bottom NavigationView que pasara por diferentes fragment al pulsar sobre su correspondiente icono, al igual busqué en Youtube un tutorial para hacerlo y ya quedó, el problema es que un fragment al que quiero pasar, tiene la conexion con firebase y esta siendo heredado por AppCompatActivity y para hacer el bottom necesita heredar a Fragment(Android.Support.v4) y enseguida me salta error en setContentView,findViewById y getApplicationContext)

Este es el código que me manda error al hacer la herencia

```
 public class Home extends Fragment {

    public RecyclerView mCategList;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Global");
        mDatabase.keepSynced(true);

        mCategList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.myrecycleview);
        mCategList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mCategList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Categoria, categoriaViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Categoria, categoriaViewHolder>
                (Categoria.class, R.layout.categ_row, categoriaViewHolder.class, mDatabase) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(categoriaViewHolder viewHolder, Categoria model, int position) {
            viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
            viewHolder.setImage(getApplicationContext(),model.getImage());
            }
        };
        mCategList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }

        public static class categoriaViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        {
            View mView;
            public categoriaViewHolder(View itemView)
            {
                super(itemView);
                mView=itemView;
            }
            public void setTitle(String title)
            {
                TextView post_title=(TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.post_title);
                post_title.setText(title);
            }
            public void setImage(Context ctx, String image)
            {
                ImageView post_image=(ImageView)mView.findViewById(R.id.post_image);
                Picasso.with(ctx).load(image).into(post_image);
            }
        }

    }
```

Al buscar los tips de android studio para resolver el error solo dice "Cannot resolve method 'findViewById(int)'
Y en getAplicationContext dice:
"Create Getter"

Si vuelvo a heredar a AppCompatActivity ya no me marca un error, pero necesito que herede de Fragment para poder hacer el bottom

Comment: Revisa mi respuesta para que entiendas cuando utilizar cada cosa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Primero que todo**, tienes que endender como funcionan los Context, [en este link puedes ver la diferencia y cuando utilizar cada uno](https://blog.mindorks.com/understanding-context-in-android-application-330913e32514). Luego tienes que entender la diferencia entre un [Fragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments?hl=ES) y un [Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity?hl=ES).

Segun la **"documentacion oficial"**:

Un [Fragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments?hl=ES) representa un comportamiento o una parte de la interfaz de usuario en una [Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity?hl=ES). Puedes combinar múltiples fragmentos en una sola actividad para crear una IU multipanel y volver a usar un fragmento en múltiples actividades. Puedes pensar en un [Fragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments?hl=ES) como una sección modular de una actividad que tiene su **ciclo de vida propio**, recibe sus propios eventos de entrada y que puedes agregar o quitar mientras la actividad se esté ejecutando (algo así como una "subactividad" que puedes volver a usar en diferentes actividades).

Un [Fragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments?hl=ES) siempre debe estar integrado a una actividad y el **ciclo de vida** del fragmento se ve directamente afectado por el ciclo de vida de la actividad anfitriona. Por ejemplo, **cuando la actividad está pausada**, también lo están todos sus fragmentos, y **cuando la actividad se destruye**, lo mismo ocurre con todos los fragmentos.

Por el contrario, una [Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity?hl=ES), es una actividad o pantalla única y enfocada que el usuario puede hacer. Casi todas las actividades interactúan con el usuario, por lo que la clase Actividad se ocupa de crear una ventana para usted en la que puede colocar su Interfaz de usuario **setContentView(View)**. Cuando se inicia una nueva actividad, se coloca en la parte superior de la pila y se convierte en la actividad de ejecución: la actividad previa siempre permanece debajo de ella en la pila y no volverá a aparecer en primer plano hasta que la nueva actividad salga.

En la siguiente imagen te puedes dar cuenta que las [Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity?hl=ES) definen un ciclo de vida diferente a la de los [Fragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments?hl=ES) y cada [Fragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments?hl=ES)debe ser creado por una [Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity?hl=ES).

[image: Ciclo de vida del Fragment y Activity]

Ahora bien, tal como muestra el grafico y pudiste leer en la documentación, no puedes utilizar **setContentView** porque solo son parte de las [Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity?hl=ES). Por lo que obviamente te muestra tu error.

Un ejemplo de como se infla la vista en un Fragment (similar a hacer `setContentView`) moldeando tu codigo deberia quedar asi:

... Tu codigo tal como esta, solo que eliminas el `onCreate` y reemplazarlo por este:

```
public class Home extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflar o cargar el layout para el Fragment
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
        // Para hacer findViewById, debes hacerlo con la referencia de root que es tu layout
        // Ejemplo: TextView textView = root.findViewById(R.id.textView);

        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Global");
        mDatabase.keepSynced(true);

        mCategList = (RecyclerView) root.findViewById(R.id.myrecycleview);
        mCategList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mCategList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        return root;
    }
}
```

... Tu codigo tal como esta, cambia `getApplicationContext()` por `getContext()` en el `onStart()`.

Ahora bien, si ya entendiste como **cargar** o **inflar** una vista en un [Fragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments?hl=ES), debes saber que para iniciar una [Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity?hl=ES) y un [Fragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments?hl=ES) tambien debe ser diferente. Las [Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity?hl=ES) son iniciadas via Intent, mientras que los Fragments deben ser iniciados via Transacciones para poder implementar su ciclo de vida funcional. [Puedes ver mas informacion en esta respuesta que hice](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/163337/38154).

Comment: Muchas gracias, creo que sí, debería bien entender todos los conceptos, muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de explicarme detalladamente, ya mismo lo estoy entendiendo, muchas gracias por tu respuesta!

Comment: @EdgarSaenz si puedes leete bien lo de los Context, te pueden ayudar a ahorrarte mucha memoria, sobretodo cuando usas Picasso o Glide para cargar imagenes. Muchas de las imagenes son cargadas a la cache y puede llegarte a dar errores de memoria (Out of memory) ya que los recursos en el celular son mas limitados que en una aplicacion de escritorio. Si algun dia te topas con ese tipo de errores, [puedes ver este tip](https://goo.gl/4StiA4) que hice para ayudarte a prevenir errores de memoria con librerías como [Glide](https://goo.gl/AY6KMq) (es mas potente que Picasso y tiene mejor performance).

Answer (score 0):

No te preocupes es un error muy simple, estás confundiendo Fragment con Activity te paso el código de como sería para el fragment.

```
public class Home extends Fragment {

    public RecyclerView mCategList;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
 mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Global");
        mDatabase.keepSynced(true);

        mCategList = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.myrecycleview);
        mCategList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mCategList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(v.getContext()));
return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Categoria, categoriaViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Categoria, categoriaViewHolder>
                (Categoria.class, R.layout.categ_row, categoriaViewHolder.class, mDatabase) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(categoriaViewHolder viewHolder, Categoria model, int position) {
            viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
            viewHolder.setImage(getContext(),model.getImage());
            }
        };
        mCategList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }



        public static class categoriaViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        {
            View mView;
            public categoriaViewHolder(View itemView)
            {
                super(itemView);
                mView=itemView;
            }
            public void setTitle(String title)
            {
                TextView post_title=(TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.post_title);
                post_title.setText(title);
            }
            public void setImage(Context ctx, String image)
            {
                ImageView post_image=(ImageView)mView.findViewById(R.id.post_image);
                Picasso.with(ctx).load(image).into(post_image);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Wow muchas gracias! Soy nuevo en esto, pero bueno de los errores se aprende, me acabas de ayudar como no te imaginas, mil gracias!