# ¿Como ir de un Activity "A" a un Activity "B" para seleccionar datos y volver al Activity "A" sin que los editText del Activity "A" se Borren?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent

Tengo la necesidad de en una "Activity A" llamar a una "Activity B" para seleccionar datos y mandarlos a la "Activity A", pero en la "Activity A" tengo 10 edit text que al hacer esas transiciones con intents se borran , y no quisiera pasar todos los datos de un activity a otro para volverlos a regresar.

los llamados a las activitys los hago con intents comunes y los envios de datos con bundle, aqui un ejemplo desde la "Activity B"

```
bundle.putString("Location", mList.get(position));
bundle.putInt("Type",3);
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, ActivityA.class);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Como dice @Jorgesys en su comentario, no tienes que abrir una nueva actividad A, lo que tienes que hacer es volver a la que ya tenías abierta y seguirás teniendo los datos en los edit text.

Answer (score 3):

Regularmente no debes realizar un Intent para "regresar" a una Activity a menos que tengas implementado cargar los datos desde una fuente persistente, por ejemplo una base de datos o un archivo.

Lo que deseas realizar lo puedes lograr simplemente agregando el método `onBackPressed()` a tu `Activity` B:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    this.finish();
}
```

de esta forma al dar click en el botón "back" de tu dispositivo se cierra la Activity B y regresas a la Activity A que fue previamente cargada y no tienes que recargarla.

---

Si deseas enviar datos de `Activity B` a `Activity A` entonces puedes realizarlo mediante un `bundle` con los datos y estos sean enviados en un `Intent`, puedes revisar esta pregunta:

[Enviar datos entre activities](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36902/enviar-datos-entre-activities)

Envia los agrega los datos en en bundle y envialos en el `Intent`:

```
bundle.putString("Location", mList.get(position));
bundle.putInt("Type",3);
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, ActivityA.class);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

Para recibirlos en Activity A, puedes realizarlo dentro del método `onCreate()`:

```
 Bundle parametros = this.getIntent().getExtras();

 String datos = "";
 int tipo = 0;
 if(parametros !=null){
    String datos = parametros.getString("Location"); 
    int tipo = parametros.getInt("Type"); 
 }
```

y posteriormente estos valores puedes agregarlos a tus `EditText`, por ejemplo:

```
editTextDatos.setText(datos);
editTextDatos.setText(String.valueOf(tipo)); //* Los valores int debes convertirlos a String para usar el método setText()
```

Comment: tienes razón , pero mi mayor problema es entonces el mandar los datos que seleccione en la Activity B a la Activity A

Comment: En ese caso agrega los datos en un bundle si es que los tienes en Activity B y de esta forma envíalos a Activity A, revisa la actualización.

Answer (score 0):

Debes guardar el estado de tu actividad.
utiliza el metodo override `SaveInstanceState` y guarde todos sus datos.
En `onCreate`, si savedInstanceState no es nulo, restaure todos sus datos y establezca todos los campos.

Concepto Android studio (Guardar el estado de tu actividad): Cuando tu actividad comienza a detenerse, el sistema llama a onSaveInstanceState() para que tu actividad pueda guardar la información de estado con una colección de pares clave-valor . La implementación predeterminada de este método guarda información acerca del estado de la jerarquía de vistas de la actividad, como el texto en un widget EditText o la posición de desplazamiento de un ListView.

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    savedInstanceState.putInt("MY_FIELD", 43);
    // ... other fields


    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); // Always call the superclass first


    if (savedInstanceState != null) {

        int value = savedInstanceState.getInt("MY_FIELD");

        // ... update your views


    } else {
        // no previous state, start fresh
    }

}
```

Mas detalles: [Aquí](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating)

Comment: Hola jeanpitx me parece que aunque se agreguen los datos en onSavedInstanceState() el problema es que el OP realiza un Intent a la Activity, como es un nuevo Intent entonces no cargaría los datos.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno después averiguar más y pensar hallé una solución hace unos días pero se me olvido publicarla 
La publico para aquellos que alguna vez se encuentren en la misma situación o una similar
Lo que hice fue muy simple , las variables que necesitaba que agarren un valor en la Activity B las declare como variables "public static" desde la Activity A, para que de esta manera pueda cambiar los valores desde la Activity B (o cualquier otra activity) y ya no depender de un Bundle para pasar los datos entre Activitys, lo siguiente que hice siguiendo el consejo de Jorgesys fue llamar al metodo .finish(); para que la Activity B termine , volviendo a la Activity A sin perder ningún dato de los editText y habiendo cambiado los valores de las variables que necesitaba.
A continuacion dejo un ejemplo en código:

Activity A:

```
public static int variableA;
public static String stringB;
```

Activity B:

```
import static  miProyecto.ActivityA.variableA;
import static  miProyecto.ActivityA.stringB;

/*clase y metodos...*/
.
.
.

variableA=3;
stringB="nuevo valor";
this.finish(); //o puedes utilizar el metodo onBackPressed();
```

Vale recalcar que para usar las variables static las tienes que importar, después de eso su uso es como el de una variable normal

Comment: Buenas, he usado este "truco" y me ha funcionado bien. Lo único que al volver al Activity A, no me traía los valores de vuelta, a menos que los leyera desde el método OnRestart()