# Como pasar un valor de MainActivity a otra Activity

Tags: android, android-fragment, datetime

Estoy tratando de hace run reloj que se actualize cada segundo....el reloj funciona bien lo todo lo ago directo en la misma clase de "MainActivity".
Pero mi idea es hacer una lista con 10 cosas y cada lista ponga la fecha, entonces en la la MainActivity tengo la funcion del reloj de la siguiente manera.

mainActivity

```
   public void currentTime() {
        Thread t = new Thread() {
            private volatile String tt;
            @Override
            public void run(){
                try {
                    while (!isInterrupted()) {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        runOnUiThread((new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                TextView tdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.currentTime);
                                long date = System.currentTimeMillis();
                                SimpleDateFormat adf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
                                String dateString = adf.format(date);
                                tt = dateString;
                            }
                        }));


                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                }
            }
            public String getValue() { return tt;  }
        };
        t.start();
    }
```

Pero no encuentro de que forma regresar el valor del reloj para poderlo poner en un " textview".
La unica idea que se me ocurrio no me funciono

```
 public classLista (MainActivity mainActivity) {

        this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
    }
     vista.timpo.setText(mainActivity.getValue());
```

alguna idea de como puedo regresar el valor.

Comment: ¿Regresar el valor a dónde, a otra `Activity`?

Comment: @A.Cedano asi es amigo, creo que no escirbi bien la pregunta.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36902/enviar-datos-entre-activities)

Comment: En la pregunta que enlaza @alex55132 se explica muy bien cómo hacer lo que quieres.