# Como enviar datos de una activity a otra en android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, programación-móvil

Lo que pasa es que el RESULTADO de la SUMA del activity IngresarDatos lo quiero reflejar en otra activity pero no se como hacerlo

IngresarDatos.java

```
package com.example.asus.crudaplicacion;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class IngresarDatos extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    EditText e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,e6;
    Button bt1,bt2;
    TextView t1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ingresar_datos);
        e1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtHora);
        e2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtPsicologo);
        e3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtTrabajador);
        e4=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtMedico);
        e5=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtTraumatologo);
        e6=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtOtro);
        t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.hora);
        bt1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSumar);
        bt2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnEnviar);
        bt2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),GuardarDatos.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        bt1.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int valor1=Integer.parseInt(e2.getText().toString());
        int valor2=Integer.parseInt(e3.getText().toString());
        int valor3=Integer.parseInt(e4.getText().toString());
        int valor4=Integer.parseInt(e5.getText().toString());
        int valor5=Integer.parseInt(e6.getText().toString());
        int s=valor1+valor2+valor3+valor4+valor5;
        t1.setText(s+"");

    }


}
```

activity_ingresar_datos.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".IngresarDatos">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Hora ingreso:"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/edtHora"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtHora"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Psicologo:"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/edtPsicologo"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.547"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtPsicologo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edtHora" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Trabajador Social:"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/edtTrabajador"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtTrabajador"
        android:layout_width="166dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edtPsicologo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Medico:"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/edtMedico"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.585"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtMedico"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edtTrabajador" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Traumatologo:"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/edtTraumatologo"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView6" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtTraumatologo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edtMedico" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Otro:"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/edtOtro"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.659"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView7" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtOtro"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edtTraumatologo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hora"
        android:layout_width="111dp"
        android:layout_height="29dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Hora Salida:"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.089"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView8" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSumar"
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Sumar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/hora" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnEnviar"
        android:layout_width="168dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Enviar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnSumar" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

GuardarDatos.java

```
package com.example.asus.crudaplicacion;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class GuardarDatos extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_guardar_datos);
    }
}
```

En esta activity quiero que se refleje el resultado de la suma.

Comment: ya hay varias respuestas para esto, es question de buscar. Un ejemplo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36902/enviar-datos-entre-activities

Comment: Como comenta armen trata de buscar en el sitio la información, tal vez ya exista. @nicolasyo1WWE en onClick(View v) { agrega el intent para enviar los datos a la activity GuardarDatos, si tienes duda pregunta.

Comment: y porque las respuestas que son correctas tiene -1 ? .. a que se debe ?

Answer (score -1):

por favor intenta buscar en google.

```
Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),GuardarDatos.class);

 intent.putExtra("total", t1.getText());
startActivity(i);
```

y en la otra .

```
String valor = getIntent().getStringExtra("total");
```

Answer (score -1):

pues te recomiendo utilizar tu intent para enviarlo de esta forma

```
i.putExtra("suma", aqui pones la variable del resultado y concatenas con .toString);
```

en la siguiente actividad donde vas a recibir, agregas una variable donde recibes

```
int recibirsuma;
```

luego en el  oncreate vas a verificar si el envio es nulo para que la app no se te cierre en caso que lo sea

```
if (getIntent().getExtras() !=null){recibirsuma=Integer.parseInt(getIntent().getExtras().getString("suma"));}
```

asi envias y recibes, tambien puedes enviar el tipo de dato con un putInt,putString y los demás tipos de valores, espero haberte ayudado