# Pasar objetos entre actividades Android

Tags: android, activity, objeto

Tengo una actividad donde se rellenan una serie de campos. En ella tengo un botón donde al pulsar me abre un recyclerView, el cual presenta los datos de una tabla. Al seleccionar uno de los items del RecyclerView, quiero que se pase el objeto a la actividad primera y ponga muestre el atributo nombre en un editext. ¿ Cómo puedo hacer para conservar los datos del formulario de la primera actividad?. Así es como lo tengo pero no me funciona:
Actividad2:

```
            Proyecto proyectoseleccionado;
            proyectoseleccionado= (Proyecto)listaProyecto.get(recyclerViewProyectos.getChildAdapterPosition(v));
            //Muestro con un Toast el objeto seleccionado
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),proyectoseleccionado.getNombre(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Envío el objeto seleccionado a Registro Dietas
            Intent intent = new Intent(ListaProyectosActivity.this,RegistroDietasActivity.class);

            Bundle bundle= new Bundle();
            bundle.putSerializable("proyecto",proyectoseleccionado);

            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivityForResult(intent,1);
```

Actividad 1 donde recibe el objeto:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Bundle objetoRecibido = data.getExtras();
    Proyecto proyectoseleccionado=null;
    Usuario usuarioseleccionado =null;

    if (requestCode ==1 && requestCode==RESULT_OK){
        proyectoseleccionado = (Proyecto) objetoRecibido.getSerializable("proyecto");
        if (proyectoseleccionado !=null)
            txtProyecto.setText(proyectoseleccionado.getNombre().toString());
    }
   
}
```

La verdad es que no sé si debo hacerlo con el ActivityResult....

Comment: No es correcto en onActivityResult() y es suficiente con startActivity() . El único problema que noto es que deberías obtener el objeto en el método onCreate(), ya que se envió mediante un Intent a la actividad. Asegura que tu objeto implemente la clase Serializable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ya lo he conseguido

En la primera actividad llamo a la segunda de esta manera:

```
            Intent miIntent=new Intent(RegistroDietasActivity.this,ListaProyectosActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(miIntent,1);
```

En la segunda actividad cuando selecciona un Item envio el resultado a la primera de esta forma:

```
            Proyecto proyectoseleccionado;
            proyectoseleccionado= (Proyecto)listaProyecto.get(recyclerViewProyectos.getChildAdapterPosition(v));
            //Muestro con un Toast el objeto seleccionado
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),proyectoseleccionado.getNombre(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Envío el objeto seleccionado a Registro Dietas
            Intent intent = new Intent(ListaProyectosActivity.this,RegistroDietasActivity.class);

            Bundle bundle= new Bundle();
            bundle.putSerializable("proyecto",proyectoseleccionado);

            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
            finish();
```

De nuevo en la primera actividad recojo el objeto de esta forma:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Bundle objetoRecibido = data.getExtras();
    Proyecto proyectoseleccionado=null;
    Usuario usuarioseleccionado =null;
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"He llegado",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if (requestCode == 1 ){
        proyectoseleccionado = (Proyecto) objetoRecibido.getSerializable("proyecto");
        if (proyectoseleccionado !=null)
            txtProyecto.setText(proyectoseleccionado.getNombre().toString());
    }
    if (requestCode ==2 ){
        usuarioseleccionado = (Usuario) objetoRecibido.getSerializable("usuario");
        if (usuarioseleccionado !=null)
            txtUsuario.setText(usuarioseleccionado.getNombre().toString());

    }
}
```

De esta forma cuando no se me borra ningún dato del formulario.

Answer (score 3):

### Enviar objeto entre Actividades:

Una opción es implementar en tu objeto la clase [Serializable](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html):

```
public class Proyecto implements Serializable {
```

Enviarias un objeto en el `Intent` mediante `.putExtra()` (no es necesario usar `startActivityForResult()` ) :

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SegundaActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("proyecto", proyectoseleccionado);
                startActivity(intent);
```

Para recibir el objeto en la `Activity` se realiza de esta forma, recibiéndolo dentro del método `onCreate()` (NO en `onActivityResult()` ):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     ...
     ...
     Proyecto  proyectoseleccionado = (Proyecto) getIntent().getSerializable("proyecto");
     ...
     ...

}
```

Comment: la opcion de @jorgesys es buena otra opcion seria convertir el objecto en json String con la libreria GSON lo pasas como un string y luego lo decodificas en la otra actividad con la misma libreria saludos.