# Pasar objeto de una actividad a otra Android

Tags: java, android

Estoy buscando la manera de pasar un objeto hacia otra actividad.

Lo que hago es crearlo en una actividad. Y en la otra quiero recibirlo y trabajar con él. Intente pasando dato por dato del objeto con `intent.putExtra()` pero no es la forma mas practica de trabajar.

Acá dejo un ejemplo:

```
i.putExtra("nombre", jsonObject.optString("name"));
i.putExtra("apellido", jsonObject.optString("lastname"));
i.putExtra("telefono", jsonObject.optString("phone"));
i.putExtra("direccion", jsonObject.optString("address"));
i.putExtra("email", jsonObject.optString("usuario"));
```

Y en la otra actividad lo creo:

```
usuario.setNombre(getIntent().getStringExtra("nombre"));
usuario.setApellido(getIntent().getStringExtra("apellido"));
usuario.setDireccion(getIntent().getStringExtra("direccion"));
usuario.setEmail(getIntent().getStringExtra("email"));
usuario.setTelefono(getIntent().getStringExtra("telefono"));
```

Me gustaría crearlo en la primera actividad y pasarlo como un objeto en vez de pasar dato por dato.  Gracias.

Comment: Prueba a serializar tu objeto en un objeto JSON, así podrás pasarlo de una vez y no pasando sus propiedades de una en una. Lo pasas como un string y luego, en la actividad que lo recibes lo deserializas al objeto que quieras.

Comment: Buenos días @Juampi, creo que tu pregunta podría ser resulta en la respuesta de jorgesys de esta pregunta, fíjate si te sirve https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/215399/pasar-objetos-entre-actividades-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La clase Usuario debe implementar la interfaz Serializable:

```
public class Usuario implements Serializable{
    .
    .
    .
    public void Usuario(){};
    //Metodos y constructores
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Y para pasarlo por intent, debes pasarlo como un simple extra.

```
intent.putExtra("nombre_del_identificador", referenciaDeUsuario// O simplemente usuario);
```

Para recuperar el objeto en una Activity:

```
getIntent().getSerializableExtra("nombre_del_identificador");
```

Con lo anterior puedes crear una referencia de tipo Usuario en la Activity B y así poder usar sus atributos como te plazca.

**Observación:**
Este método es muy bueno para objetos pequeños como Usuario, no intentes pasar ingentes cantidades de datos mediante la implementación de Serializable.

Comment: Solucionado! Muchas gracias funcionó!