# ayuda con enviar datos a dos activitys

Tags: android, android-intent

mi problema es que no se como puedo dirigir los datos a dos activitys del item seleccionado...soy novato y estaba probando con el if y me parece que esta mal porque ya no puedo seleccionar los demás item.

```
viewHolder.setOnClickListener(new ViewHolder.ClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                    String mTitle = getItem(position).getTitle();
                    String mDesc = getItem(position).getDescripcion();
                    String mImage = getItem(position).getImage();
                    String mLugar = getItem(position).getLugar();

                    if(position ==0){
                    Intent intent=new Intent(view.getContext(),PostDetailActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("image", mImage);
                    intent.putExtra("title", mTitle);
                    intent.putExtra("descripcion", mDesc);
                    intent.putExtra("lugar",mLugar);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    if(position ==0){
                    Intent intent=new 
                    Intent(view.getContext(),PostDetail2Activity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("image", mImage);
                    intent.putExtra("title", mTitle);
                    intent.putExtra("descripcion", mDesc);
                    intent.putExtra("lugar",mLugar);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onItemLongClick(View view, int position) {
                }
            });
            return viewHolder;
```

en esta `activity` le puse un botón para ingresar a la otra `activity` pero me sale vacía:

```
    String image =getIntent().getStringExtra("image");
    String title=getIntent().getStringExtra("title");
    String desc=getIntent().getStringExtra("descripcion");
    String lug=getIntent().getStringExtra("lugar");

    mTitleTv.setText(title);
    mDetailTv.setText(desc);
    Picasso.get().load(image).into(mImageIv);

    mBtn_hora.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent =new Intent(PostDetailActivity.this,PostDetail2Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Te has dado cuenta que has puesto if (position == 0) en los dos casos??

Comment: si... pero en tal caso que le podria cambiar para que no se cancelen los demas item y poder visualizar con el boton que puse...

Comment: en la llamada que haces desde el mBtn_hora no estas poniendo los extras al Intent y por eso no te salen, no se si te refieres a eso.

Comment: Esto no tendrá que ver con guardar el estado de la activity? ya que cada intent mata la anterior. y al iniciar otra tendria que haber una funcion en el OnCreate(){}

Comment: creo que si, le pondria... intent.putExtra("image", image)?? en la llamada del mBtn_hora

Comment: Si, como lo tienes puesto arriba, piensa que estas definiendo un Intent nuevo, y entonces tienes que poner todo lo que quieras que pase al nuevo activity.

Comment: sii... por fin ya me salio, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

despues de cada

```
startActivity(intent);
```

agrega `finish()`

```
startActivity(intent);
finish()
```

y cacha los intens que mandas en tu segunda activity

Comment: ok... gracias por responder!

Comment: Te funciono? si te funciono por favor puntúa la respuesta para futuras personas con el mismo problema saludos.

Comment: Esto no responde a la pregunta "como puedo dirigir los datos a dos activitys".

Comment: finish() no es necesario, puedes iniciar la segunda actividad aunque la primera no finalice y aun así enviar/recibir datos.

Answer (score 0):

Te sugiero primeramente revises esta pregunta:

[Enviar datos entre activities](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36902/enviar-datos-entre-activities/36924#36924)

Si estas enviando los datos hacia `PostDetail2Activity`

```
 Intent intent=new Intent(view.getContext(),PostDetail2Activity.class);
 intent.putExtra("image", mImage);
 intent.putExtra("title", mTitle);
 intent.putExtra("descripcion", mDesc);
 intent.putExtra("lugar",mLugar);
 startActivity(intent);
```

para recibir correctamente los datos debes recibirlos dentro del método `onCreate()` de tu `Activity` , en este caso `PostDetail2Activity` que definiste en el `Intent` :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     String image =getIntent().getStringExtra("image");
     String title=getIntent().getStringExtra("title");
     String desc=getIntent().getStringExtra("descripcion");
     String lug=getIntent().getStringExtra("lugar");

    ...
    ...
```

}

Comment: gracias por la explicación!

Comment: Ya revisaste esto se cumpla? en ocasiones se trata de recibir los valores en otro lugar que no es onCreate() y esa es la razón de no recibir el bundle con los valores, comenta que resultados obtuviste para dar seguimiento a tu pregunta, saludos!

Comment: si, solo me faltaba poner los intent para pasar los datos y aparte el Intent intent=new Intent(view.getContext(),PostDetail2Activity.class); lo cambie por Intent intent=new Intent(PostDetailActivity.this,PostDetail2Activity.class); me generara algun problemas más adelante por ese cambio??

Comment: Si estas creando el intent desde la Activity llamada PostDetailActivity, esto es correcto y no provocaría problemas  intent=new Intent(PostDetailActivity.this,PostDetail2Activity.class);