# Cómo pasar datos que leo de un NFC a otra activity en android

Tags: android-studio, nfc

Estoy comenzando a trabajar en una aplicación en Android Studio, en la cuál escribo y leo un NFC. Lo que necesito es que el string que estoy leyendo lo pueda pasar a otro Activity. Estoy recién en esto y no he podido lograrlo, agradezco cualquier ayuda!

Acá les dejo mi código:

MainActivity

```
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.nfc.NdefMessage;
import android.nfc.NdefRecord;
import android.nfc.NfcAdapter;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.nfc.tech.Ndef;
import android.nfc.tech.NdefFormatable;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

NfcAdapter nfcAdapter;
EditText txtTagContent;
Button write, read;
public TextView contenido;
public String mensaje;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    txtTagContent = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtTagContent);


    write = (Button)findViewById(R.id.write);
    read = (Button)findViewById(R.id.read);

    contenido = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.contenido);

}

@Override
protected  void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

    enableForegroundDispatchSystem();
}

@Override
protected  void onPause(){
    super.onPause();

    disableForegroundDispatchSystem();
}
private NdefMessage createNdefMessage(String content){

    NdefRecord ndefRecord = createTextRecord(content);

    NdefMessage ndefMessage =
            new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[] {ndefRecord});
    Log.e("mensaje que escribo", content);



    return ndefMessage;
}
@Override
protected  void onNewIntent(final Intent intent){
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

    if(intent.hasExtra(nfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG))
    {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Encontrado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        write.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
                NdefMessage ndefMessage = createNdefMessage(txtTagContent.getText()+"");

                writeNdefMessage(tag, ndefMessage);
            }
        });

        read.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {


              Parcelable[] parcelables = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);


               if(parcelables != null && parcelables.length > 0)
                {
                   readTextFromMessage((NdefMessage) parcelables[0]);


                }else{
                   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No NDEF messages found!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }



            }
        });





    }
}

private void readTextFromMessage(NdefMessage ndefMessage) {

  NdefRecord[] ndefRecords = ndefMessage.getRecords();

   if(ndefRecords != null && ndefRecords.length>0){

      NdefRecord ndefRecord = ndefRecords[0];

        String tagContent = getTextFromNdefRecord(ndefRecord);


       contenido.setText(tagContent);


   }else
    {
       Toast.makeText(this, "No NDEF records found!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}

private void enableForegroundDispatchSystem(){

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_REPLACE_PENDING);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 , intent, 0);
    IntentFilter[] intentFilters = new IntentFilter[]{};

    nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, intentFilters, null);


}

private void disableForegroundDispatchSystem(){
nfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
}

private void formatTag(Tag tag, NdefMessage ndefMessage){
    try{

        NdefFormatable ndefFormatable = NdefFormatable.get(tag);
        if(ndefFormatable == null){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Tag is not ndef formatable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        ndefFormatable.connect();
        ndefFormatable.format(ndefMessage);
        ndefFormatable.close();
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("FormatTag", e.getMessage());

    }

}

private void writeNdefMessage(Tag tag, NdefMessage ndefMessage){
    try{
        if(tag == null)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Tag object cannot be null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);

        if(ndef==null){
            formatTag(tag, ndefMessage);
        }
        else{
            ndef.connect();
            if(!ndef.isWritable()){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Tag is not writable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                ndef.close();
                return;
            }

            ndef.writeNdefMessage(ndefMessage);
            ndef.close();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Mensaje guardado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }catch (Exception e){
    Log.e("writeNdefMessage", e.getMessage() );
    }
}

private NdefRecord createTextRecord(String content){
    try{
        byte[] language;
        language = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().getBytes("UTF-8");

        final byte[] text = content.getBytes("UTF-8");
        final int languageSize = language.length;
        final int textLength = text.length;
        final ByteArrayOutputStream payload = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1 + languageSize + textLength);

        payload.write((byte) (languageSize & 0x1F));
        payload.write(language, 0, languageSize);
        payload.write(text, 0, textLength);

        return new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN, NdefRecord.RTD_TEXT, new byte[0], payload.toByteArray());

    }catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e){
        Log.e("createTextRecord", e.getMessage());
    }

    return  null;
}




  public String getTextFromNdefRecord(NdefRecord ndefRecord)
  {
    String tagContent = null;
    try {
        byte[] payload = ndefRecord.getPayload();
        String textEncoding = ((payload[0] & 128) == 0) ? "UTF-8" : "UTF- 
    16";
        int languageSize = payload[0] & 0063;
        tagContent = new String(payload, languageSize + 1,
                payload.length - languageSize - 1, textEncoding);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
       Log.e("getTextFromNdefRecord", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    return tagContent;
   }
  }
```

LeerActivity (activity en el cual quiero recibir el contenido del NFC)

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LeerActivity  extends AppCompatActivity {


public TextView leer_nfc;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.leer);

    leer_nfc = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.leer_nfc);


}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

El envió de esta información se puede realizar de la misma forma que se envian datos entre Actividades:

[Enviar datos entre activities](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36902/enviar-datos-entre-activities/36924#36924)

Se realiza mediante un Bundle en el cual se agregan valores y ese bundle se envía a través de un `Intent` hacia la Activity destino.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LeerActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("valorNFC", valorAEnviarNFC);
startActivity(intent);
```

Dentro de el método `onCreate()` de LeerActivity obtendría el valor mediante `getExtras()`.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LeerActivity  extends AppCompatActivity {

public TextView leer_nfc;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.leer);

    leer_nfc = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.leer_nfc);

    if(getIntent().getExtras() !=null){
      if(getIntent().getExtras().containsKey("valorNFC")) {
       String valorNFCrecibido = getIntent().getExtras().getString("valorNFC");
      leer_nfc.setText(valorNFCrecibido);
      }
    }


}

}
```