# Como vincular el path de un item (imagenes) de un recyclerview a selectedImagePath desde OnActivityResult

Tags: java, android

Tengo una actividad que muestra un recyclerview con productos de una base de datos, imagenes, nombre.

Y otra actividad que es un editor de fotos, como lo hago para que cuando el usuario de click a un determinado elemento del recyclerview, envíe ese elemento al editor de fotos. Ya tengo en la actividad principal con el intent putExtra y el editor de fotos la recibe getExtras. GetStrings. SelectedImagePath.

Solo he podido hacerlo con imágenes de la galería en OnActivityResult.
¿Cómo puedo hacer que en lugar de tomar el path de un elemento de la galería de imagenes, vincule el path de un item del recyclerview a SelectedImagePath? Gracias

Es decir, a través de un intent en algún elemento de recyclerview, agregue como valor el path de ese item a la variable SelectedPathImage.

Este código vincula el PATH de una imagen de la galería a la variable SelectedImagePath, luego, en la clase del editor de fotos, toma el valor de selectedImagePath con GetExtra.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (resultCode) {
            case RESULT_CANCELED:
                break;
            case RESULT_OK:
                if (requestCode == GALLERY_INTENT_CALLED || requestCode == CAMERA_CODE
                        || requestCode == GALLERY_KITKAT_INTENT_CALLED) {
                    if (requestCode == GALLERY_INTENT_CALLED) {
                        selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                        selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                    } else if (requestCode == GALLERY_KITKAT_INTENT_CALLED) {
                        selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                        final int takeFlags = data.getFlags()
                                & (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
                        // Check for the freshest data.
                        if (selectedImageUri != null) {
                            getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(
                                    selectedImageUri, takeFlags);
                            selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                        }
                    } else {
                        selectedImagePath = selectedOutputPath;
                    }
```

Para cargar las imagenes utilizo picasso

```
String imageUrl = Constants.RECENT_PRODUCT_IMAGE_URL + product.getImage_name();
        Picasso.get().load(imageUrl).into(holder.ivProductImage);
```

En mi anterior proyecto, el editor de fotos, tenia un mainActivity el cual tenia dos metodos, seleccionar imagen de la galeria, o hacerse una foto.

```
public class MainActivity extends MediaActivity {
//MainActiviy extends MediaActivity que a su vez hace extends a a la clase Baseactivity.

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maino);
    }

    public void openUserGallery(View view) {
        openGallery();
    }

    public void openUserCamera(View view) {
        startCameraActivity();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPhotoTaken() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PhotoEditorActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("shared_path", selectedImagePath);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Pase el onactivityresult a la Activity editor de fotos como me indicaste.

```
case RESULT_OK:
                if (requestCode == SHARED_PATH) {
                    if (requestCode == SHARED_PATH) {
                        String path = data.getStringExtra("shared_path");
                        selectedImagePath = path;
                    } else {
                        selectedImagePath = selectedOutputPath;
    //Posteriormente sigue decodificando la imagen, encontrando la escala correcta...
```

Y el intent en el adapter del recyclerview lo hice de esta manera.

```
public void onClick(View v) {

            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            Product product = productList.get(position);

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, PhotoEditorActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("shared_path", selectedImagePath);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Ahora el editor de fotos toma el string de esta manera, si intento iniciar la actividad A como me dijiste me dice error por non-static method.

```
String selectedImagePath = getIntent().getExtras().getString("selectedImagePath");
```

Comment: Revisa [Enviar datos entre Actividades](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/36924/95), saludos

Comment: Te revisé tu nueva pregunta y ví el problema. Lo que pasa es que cuando es una URL de un servidor externo, debes cargar las imágenes con un método diferente. Ví que utilizaban Bitmap.DecodeFile. sin embargo, esto solo sirve para imágenes locales. Si quieres cargar una imagen desde un servidor web. Intenta cargarla igual que las cargas en el RecyclerView o utiliza una librería de imágenes como Glide. Es mejor que Picasso en muchos aspectos. O si quieres seguir con Picasso, en el onCreate donde recibes el path. Pasale ese mismo a Picasso. Te debe funcionar.

Comment: @Andrespegineer Muchisimas gracias muy amable, no hubiera podido sin usted, investigue mucho. Mira que el editor de fotos era un proyecto aparte en github.

Answer (score 0):

Antes que todo puedes mirarte está respuesta:

[Enviar datos entre activities](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/36905/38154)

---

Asumiendo que:

`Activity A`: es donde está el `RecyclerView` (desde donde quieres enviar el path).

Debes crear un `RequestCode`:

```
public static final int SHARED_PATH = 10010;
```

Luego, `Activity B`: es el Activity editor de fotos (donde quieres recibir el path de `Activity A`).

Desde el `Activity B`. Debes hacer iniciar la `Activity A` de la siguiente manera:

`B.startActivityForResult(A, A.SHARED_PATH)`. Luego en A al seleccionar el item del `RecyclerView`, debes hacer:

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(); 
resultIntent.putExtra("shared_path", /*Aqui pasas el path*/);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
finish();
```

Inmediatamente hagas esto. En tu `Activity B` en el`onActivityResult` te llegará el resultado de A. Por lo que tendrías que validar el `RequestCode` así:

```
. . .

case RESULT_OK:
        if(requestCode == A.SHARED_PATH)
        {
             String path = data.getStringExtra("shared_path"); 
        }

. . .
```

Si quieres guardar la imagen modificada, de manera local, debes hacer:

```
public String IMAGE_PATH = "PHOTO_EDIT_IMG_";
public String IMAGE_PNG_EXT = ".png";
public String DIRECTORY_NAME = "/PhotoEdit";
```

Luego:

```
// Crea un directorio si no existe, y guarda la imagen local modificada
private void createDirectoryAndSaveFile(Bitmap imageToSave, String fileName) {

        String file_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + DIRECTORY_NAME;
        File dir = new File(file_path);
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdirs();
        }

        File file = new File(dir, fileName);

        try {
            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
            imageToSave.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
            fOut.flush();
            fOut.close();
            makeSureFileWasCreatedThenMakeAvailable(file);
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
        }

    }

    // Con este metodo te aseguras que el archivo local se creo
    private void makeSureFileWasCreatedThenMakeAvailable(File file){
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
                new String[] { file.toString() } , null,
                new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {

                    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                        // Aqui actualizas la imagen del servidor, te devuelve el path de la imagen local
                    }
                });
    }
```

Y lo llamarias asi (digamos que tienes un boton de Subir/Actualizar imagen) al darle click:

```
// Bitmap es el bitmap de la imagen modificada
Date date = new Date();
long time = date.getTime(); // Fecha y hora de cuando fue editada la foto
createDirectoryAndSaveFile(bitmap, IMAGE_PATH + Long.toString(time) + IMAGE_PNG_EXT);
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por ayudarme, voy a hacerlo.

Comment: Quisiera añadir, que el recyclerview muestra imagenes que estan alojadas en mysql en un servidor web. Para mostrar las imagenes utilice JSON y pues el recyclerview con cardviews. Por eso estoy confundido con el PATH.

Comment: @ArlenCardona en el `OnActivityResult` vas a recibir el path que apunta al servidor web (que es el path que tiene el item del `RecyclerView` segun entiendo). Una vez recibido, que vas a hacer con ese `Path` o `Url` que recibes? debes hacer `selectedImagePath =  path;` que es lo que requerias en tu pregunta, pero luego que sigue? que intentas hacer?

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, la idea es poder editar las imagenes que estan alojadas en el servidor y que se muestran a traves del recyclerview, con texto, pegatinas, dibujo...  ya lo hice con imagenes de la galeria pero no se porque no me da el path, pero ya voy a probar con lo sugerido. Gracias de nuevo, muy amable, perdon por mi ignorancia

Comment: Ah, entonces tu problema es diferente. Tienes que guardar la version modificada de la imagen, de manera local. Por ejemplo. Si estas utilizando el Bitmap para modificar la imagen (digamos que haces merge de bitmaps) al crear las pegatinas, textos, etc... Debes guardar el Bitmap de resultado como un archivo local en el telefono. Despues hacer Update de la imagen del servidor con ese archivo local, si quieres que ese cambio se refleje para ese archivo en la nube. Nota: para eso deberias tener los permisos basicos de CRUD (Create, Read, Update and Delete) en el servidor.

Comment: @ArlenCardona ahi te adjunte un poco de mi codigo. Con ese codigo, vas a guardar la imagen que modificaste localmente (debes tener los permisos de Android para esto en el manifest). Luego, en el metodo `makeSureFileWasCreatedThenMakeAvailable` en el `onScanCompleted` debes de utilizar el codigo que te ofrece tu servicio para actualizar la imagen en el servidor, con esa que acabas de crear de manera local.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, te cuento que lo he intentado como me sugeriste pero sigo teniendo problemas con el PATH, cuando doy clic al item en el recyclerview si me redirecciona al editor de fotos, pero no esta cargando la imagen.

Comment: @ArlenCardona, puedes mostrarme como intentas cargar la foto? Edita tu pregunta y agrega esa parte del codigo, ademas del `Path` si puedes. Son 2 formas de cargar la foto. Una es con carga local y otra es desde un servicio web. Si no utilizas librerias para hacerlo, te recomiendo que utilices alguna. [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) o [Picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/) son muy buenas opciones.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por la ayuda, ya he editado la pregunta.

Comment: @ArlenCardona que valor tiene imageUrl?

Comment: Gracias, el valor de imageUrl es SERVER_PATH + "uploads/recent-products/"

Comment: @ArlenCardona Ok, asegurate de que esa URL cargue en un navegador. Recuerda que para que picasso cargue imagenes desde la URL, debes tener el permiso de INTERNET `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` en tu manifest. Tambien recuerda que Picasso no trabaja con Https, debes usar http. Si puedes muestrame un ejemplo de la Url que tienes.

Comment: Si carga la URL en un navegador, y los permisos si estan agregados en el manifest. Cree que se deba a que en vez de hacer.  
B.startActivityForResult(A, A.SHARED_PATH) hice String selectedImagePath = getIntent().getExtras().getString("selectedImagePath");

Comment: public void onClick(View v) {

            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            Product product = productList.get(position);

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, PhotoEditorActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("selectedImagePath", selectedImagePath);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }

Comment: Si puedes entra a [este chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93699/android-share-path-between-activities) creo que tu problema esta mas en el flujo entre Actividades.

Comment: No, que triste estoy, me dice que necesito minimo 20 de reputacion para poder hablar a traves del chat.

Comment: @ArlenCardona revisa esa solucion que te di.

Comment: Ya pude pasar la imagen, cuando doy clic envia el nombre de la imagen.jpg pero en el editor de fotos me esta dando error Unable to decode Stream. Hice esto.
intent.putExtra("selectedImagePath", productList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getImage_name());

Comment: Y lo recibo con Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        byte[] data = extras.getByteArray("selectedImagePath");