# Pasar valor al siguiente Activity

Tags: android-studio

Continuando con el Quiz:

No encuentro como pasar el puntaje al siguiente activity.

Por ejemplo, en el ativity 1 lanzo la primer pregunta, el puntaje obtenido se guarda en la variable valor y esta debería de enviarla al siguiente activity y mostrarla en el Id puntaje del siguiente activity y consecuente al siguiente y al siguiente. Pero no me muestra el valor estoy intentando con este trozo de código:

```
   public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.btnResp1:
                r1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.boton_redondo_error));
                valor="0";
                respuesta();
                break;
            case R.id.btnResp2:
                r2.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.boton_redondo_error));
                valor="0";
                respuesta();
                break;
            case R.id.btnResp3:
                r3.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.boton_redondo_correcto));
                valor="25";
                respuesta();
                break;
            case R.id.btnResp4:
                r4.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.boton_redondo_error));
                valor="0";
                respuesta();
                break;
        }
    }

    public void respuesta(){
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent cambio = new Intent(Ques1.this,Ques2.class);
                String MiPuntaje = valor;
                cambio.putExtra("DATO",MiPuntaje);
                startActivity(cambio);
            }
        },nextScreen);
    }
```

Y con bundle quiero mostrarla en el siguiente activity:

```
if(bundle!=null){
        String anterior=(String)bundle.get("DATO");
        antes = Integer.parseInt(anterior);    
}
```

Me pueden ayudar con esta parte, que es lo que estoy haciendo mal.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Enviar datos entre activities](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36902/enviar-datos-entre-activities)

Comment: Jose, ¿en que método de la siguiente Activity estas leyendo el bundle ?

Comment: En el metodo Respuesta.
public void respuesta(){
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent cambio = new Intent(Ques2.this,Ques3.class);
                String puntos = valor;
                cambio.putExtra("DATO",puntos);
                startActivity(cambio);
            }
        },300);
    }

Answer (score 0):

El ejemplo mas claro para recibir un valor seria de la siguiente manera,

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String anterior= extras.getString("DATO");
```

por lo que veo lo conviertes a `int` por lo tanto puedes recibirlo de la siguiente manera

```
int anterior = extras.getInt("DATO");
```

Answer (score 0):

Enviando datos de un Activity a otro Activity, ejemplo:

Desde Activity  A

```
  Intent cambio = new Intent(Ques1.this,Ques2.class);
  String MiPuntaje = valor;
  cambio.putExtra("DATO",MiPuntaje);
  startActivity(cambio);
```

En el Activity B:

```
 public class ActivityB extends Activity {
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
     if (extras == null) {
      return;
     }

     //Y este es el valor enviado por el Activity A
     String MiPuntaje = extras.getString("DATO");

   }
}
```

Comment: Zeballos
No se cual sea el error
El id donde quiero mostrar el puntaje en los 4 activitys se llama Puntaje. Eso es incorrecto?
Este codigo del activity uno al dos y me cierra la app.
'''puntitos=(TextView) findViewById ( R.id.Puntaje );
        r5.setOnClickListener(this);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if(bundle!=null){
            String anterior=(String)bundle.get("DATO");
            antes1 = Integer.parseInt(anterior);
        }
        puntitos.setText ( antes1 );'''

Comment: @JoseDanielSolis si se cierra la app verifica en el Log que error ocurre.

Comment: Zeballos, en si no entiendo como mostrar la variable en el siguiente activity y el problema es que el CountDownTimer sigue ejecutandose en el siguiente activity aunque ya halla presionado o saltado de activity y eso me produce un error.
Entonces tendria que meter un if si cualquiera de los botones fue pulsado entonces CountDownTimer parar su ejecución. Eso lo he visto con Card View pero con botones no lo he encontrado.
'''public void onFinish() {
if(correcto.getText()!="" && no11.getText()!="" && no12.getText()!="" && no13.getText()!="") {
actual1=Integer.parseInt(valor)+antes1;}'''