# Error con Bitmap.createScaledBitmap

Tags: java, android

tengo una app que trabaja con `wallpaper`, en el emulador y en los dispositivos que tengo para realizar testeos funciona perfectamente, pero en las estadisticas de los errores bloqueos del *play store*, me ha dado cuenta que en muchos dispositivos salta el siguiente error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done (AsyncTask.java:309)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion (FutureTask.java:354)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException (FutureTask.java:223)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:242)
  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run (AsyncTask.java:234)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap (Bitmap.java:610)
  at com.aaadesigner.guideffwall.infowall$SetWallpaperTask.doInBackground (infowall.java:166)
  at com.aaadesigner.guideffwall.infowall$SetWallpaperTask.doInBackground (infowall.java:139)
  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call (AsyncTask.java:295)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:237)
```

Aca les dejo mi codigo java que utilizo:

```
public class infowall extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AdView mAdView;
    private RequestOptions options;
    LinearLayout img;
    public ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private LinearLayout layoutAnimado;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_infowall);

        layoutAnimado = findViewById(R.id.animado);

        final ProgressBar progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress);

        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

        Button btnSetWallpaper = findViewById(R.id.btn);

        btnSetWallpaper.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new SetWallpaperTask().execute();
            }
        });

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        }

        this.options = new RequestOptions()
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.AUTOMATIC);


        String image_url = Objects.requireNonNull(getIntent().getExtras()).getString("img2");
        String fuente = getIntent().getExtras().getString("fuente");

        TextView tv_fuente = findViewById(R.id.fuente);

        tv_fuente.setText(fuente);

        img = findViewById(R.id.thumbnail2);
        Glide.with(this)
                .load(image_url)
                .apply(options)
                .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .error(
                        Glide
                                .with(this)
                                .load(R.drawable.error)
                )
                .into(new CustomTarget<Drawable>() {
                    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Drawable resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Drawable> transition) {
                        img.setBackground(resource);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {

                    }
                });

        TextView txtclose = findViewById(R.id.txtclose);
        txtclose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    public class SetWallpaperTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

        String image_url = Objects.requireNonNull(getIntent().getExtras()).getString("img2");

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
            Bitmap result= null;



            try {
                result = Picasso.get()
                        .load(image_url)
                        .get();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
            int height = metrics.heightPixels;
            int width = metrics.widthPixels;
            Log.e("Width", "" + width);
            Log.e("height", "" + height);
            assert result != null;
            **Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(result, width, height, true);**
            WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
            wallpaperManager.setWallpaperOffsetSteps(1, 1);
            wallpaperManager.suggestDesiredDimensions(width, height);
            try {
                wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            return result;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute () {
            super.onPreExecute();

            if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }

            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(infowall.this);
            progressDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.proceso));
            progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
            progressDialog.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute (Bitmap result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getBaseContext());
            try {
                wallpaperManager.setBitmap(result);

                progressDialog.dismiss();

                Toast toast3 = new Toast(getApplicationContext());

                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_layout,
                        (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.lytLayout));

                TextView txtMsg = layout.findViewById(R.id.txtMensaje);
                txtMsg.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.wallyes));


                toast3.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast3.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 20, 20);
                toast3.setView(layout);
                toast3.show();

                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.wallyes), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

De verdad que ni idea que puede estar causando este problema, de verdad que he leido mucho, y todos los *java* para `wallpaper` que he leido trabajan mas o menos con un codigo parecido al que he utilizado.

Lo que he intentado es que el `wallpaper` se ajuste al tamaño del dispositivo que solicita el `wallpaper`, de hecho funciona muy bien, en todos los distintos dispositivos con diferente resoluciones que lo he probado, entonces no sea a que se debera esto.

He dejado entre `** ** infowall.java:166`, que es la linea que causa el `java.lang.RuntimeException:`

Comment: El problema es que no se esta generando el bitmap debido a que el valor de la variable "result" no es una url valida o esta vacía, revisa también que uses la llave "img2" para enviar el valor, puede ser que estés usando otro valor, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

He observado tu código y veo varios puntos flacos. Pero primero voy a centrarme en el error que comentas en concreto:

Lo que ocurre es que a algunos usuarios les produce `IOException` la ejecución de Picasso *(dado por un repentino corte de conexión, timeout, etc...)* por lo tanto la descarga de la imagen se interrumpe. Se ejecuta el bloque `catch` y la variable `result` mantiene valor **`null`**

```
Bitmap result = null;
try {
    result = Picasso.get()
                    .load(image_url)
                    .get();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    // aquí result es null...
}
```

Al seguir ejecutando llegamos a este punto

```
assert result != null;
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(result, width, height, true);
```

Has de saber que `assert` no tiene ningún efecto en una aplición compilada en release, por lo que esa línea de código es como si no existiera.

La ejecución continúa y al hacer la llamada `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap` con `result = null` se produce el inesperado `NullPointerException`. Por lo tanto para solucionar ese error en concreto debes añadir `if (result != null)` antes de llamar a `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap`. Tu método doInBackground podría quedar así:

```
@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
    Bitmap result= null;

    try {
        result = Picasso.get()
                .load(image_url)
                .get();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (result != null) {
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        int height = metrics.heightPixels;
        int width = metrics.widthPixels;
        Log.e("Width", "" + width);
        Log.e("height", "" + height);
        assert result != null;
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(result, width, height, true);
        WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        wallpaperManager.setWallpaperOffsetSteps(1, 1);
        wallpaperManager.suggestDesiredDimensions(width, height);
        try {
            wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

#### Otros puntos que he observado:

1. Para tener más contexto sobre qué ocurre en tus aplicaciones, añade a tu proyecto soporte para [Crashlytics de Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/products/crashlytics) y haz `Crashlytics.logException` de todas las excepciones que captures con bloques `catch`
2. Usas dos librerías distintas para la misma funcionalidad, **Glide** y **Picasso**. Te recomiendo que optes por usar sólo una de ellas ya que al integrar las dos librerías tu apk es más grande. También hace que la misma imagen se descargue 2 veces (*doble gasto de datos al usuario*) y además se almacene 2 veces en caché (*ocupando el doble en el directorio temporal del dispositivo*).
3. La llamada a `wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);` se está realizando dos veces. Deberías eliminar esta llamada en el `onPostExecute`, y en este método únicamente notificar al usuario si la ejecución ha sido exitosa.

Comment: Hola ffernandez, Gracias por toda tu ayuda, voy a implementar tus sugerencias, y te estare escribiendo el resultado

Comment: De acuerdo @aAaDesigner Para probar el escenario que describo puedes dejar `Bitmap result` a null, sin ejecutar Picasso.get() ni el assert, y así analizar el comportamiento cuando la descarga de la imagen falle.

Comment: Te cuento hijo, agregue tu ayuda, pero ahora me salta el error en el onPostExecute.

at com.aaadesigner.guideffwall.infowall$SetWallpaperTask.onPostExecute (infowall.java:196)

Comment: ¿Has eliminado la llamada duplicada a `wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap)` que tienes en el `onPostExecute`? Como te he comentado en el último punto.

Comment: Hola hijo, ya hice ese cambio, y elimine del onPostExecute la llamada duplicada, y te cuento, ahora al aplicar el Wallpapaer, que hace todo el funcionamiento y notifica que el wallpaper ha sido colocado, queda gigante el wallpaper, es decir no se adapta a la pantalla como antes lo realizaba. es como si tomara en cuenta ahora el width, height para que se adapte a todas las pántallas como funcionaba.

Comment: Quizas estas dos lineas sean las culpables `wallpaperManager.setWallpaperOffsetSteps(1, 1);` y `wallpaperManager.suggestDesiredDimensions(width, height);`. Ya que como antes se estaba haciendo un wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap), en el onPostExecute se estaba reemplazando el wallpaper asignado dentro del doInBackground. (Se estaba asignando un wallpaper 2 veces, pero de formas diferentes)

Comment: Vale, voy a testear quitando una y dejando otra a ver y te cuento.
Le coloque el if (result != null) { en el onPostExecute  y el error no me lo esta dando, estoy testeando todo eso, y te escribo.

Answer (score 0):

El error que describes :

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException:    at
>   android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap (Bitmap.java:610)

es provocado debido a que no se genera un `Bitmap` a partir de la url especificada en la variable `result` :

```
  String image_url = Objects.requireNonNull(getIntent().getExtras()).getString("img2");
  ...
  ...

  Bitmap result= null;
    try {
        result = Picasso.get()
                .load(image_url)
                .get();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   ...
   ...         
   Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(result, width, height, true);
   ...
```

**La razón por la que no se genera el bitmap es principalmente porque no funciona la url o esta url esta vacía.**

Estas recibiendo la url de la imagen dentro de `onCreate()` lo cual es correcto

```
String image_url = Objects.requireNonNull(getIntent().getExtras()).getString("img2");
```

**Debes asegurar que es enviado este valor con el key "img2" desde la Activity fuente a la Activity destino (infowall.class), y que el valor sea una url válida,** ejemplo:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, infowall.class);   
intent.putExtra("img2", <url de imagen>);
startActivity(intent);
```

Revisa:

[Enviar datos entre activities](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36902/enviar-datos-entre-activities/36924#36924)

Comment: Hola Jorgesys, el problema es cuando falla la internet como lo indicas, las url son validas, y eso funciona bien, el detalle es cuando hay una interrupcion de la internet y falla da el error, asi como lo explico el amigo @ffernandez, espero con su ayuda logre conseguirlo