# ¿Como cargar una imagen url a otro activity cuando se seleccione un item del spinner en android studio?

Tags: android, activity

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, AdapterView.OnClickListener {

    Spinner spnlista;
    Button btnmostrar;

    int[] listaurl={R.string.Animales,R.string.Persona,R.string.Paisaje,R.string.Automovil};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        spnlista = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnlista);
        btnmostrar=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnmostrar);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> dataAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.lista_url, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spnlista.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        spnlista.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        btnmostrar.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Mostrar.class);
        //intent.putExtra("mensaje",listaurl);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String datos=getResources().getString(listaurl[position]);
        ////String datos=parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Mostrar.class);
        intent.putExtra("mensaje",String.valueOf(spnlista.getSelectedItem()));

        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Estoy tratando de que se muestre en este acitvity, la imagen url que tengo agregada internamente en el String.xml quiero saber si hay otra forma de llamar a la imagen a mi ImageView mediante client.get.

Tengo un ImageView en otro activity, y quiero que se muestre la imagen relacionada al item del spinner que esta en el activity principal.

Comment: Agregue una respuesta, te sugiero agregues como se llama el ImageView en tu clase Mostrar, ya que puse como ejemplo un ImageView con id  myImageView,  saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Es casí correcto como lo tratas de realizar mediante un `intent`, pero en este caso estas definiendo un array de valores enteros los cuales contienen el id del recurso:

```
int[] listaurl={R.string.Animales,R.string.Persona,R.string.Paisaje,R.string.Automovil};
```

Por lo tanto para obtener la url debes usar el método `getResources().getString(...)` en el cual defines el id del recurso:

```
String urlImagen = getResources().getString(listaurl[position]);
```

Esta sería la forma de enviar la url de la imagen:

```
   @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this, Mostrar.class);
        intent.putExtra("url_imagen", getResources().getString(listaurl[position]));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Te sugiero revisar:

[¿Como enviar datos entre activities?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36902/como-enviar-datos-entre-activities/36924#36924)

Ahora para cargar la imagen te sugiero usar Picasso, para esto agrega dentro de tu archivo `build.gradle` dentro del bloque `dependencies` la siguiente dependencia:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    ...
    ...
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828';
}
```

después de esto, dentro del método `onCreate()` de la clase `Mostrar`, obtén la referencia del `imageView` en tu layout mediante findViewById( ):

```
ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.myImageView);

String urlImagen = "";
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
if (b != null){
    urlImagen = b.getString("url_imagen");
    //Carga imagen en ImageView usando Picasso
    Picasso.get().load(urlImagen).into(imageView);
}
```