# Como comunicar un fragment con un activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment

Necesito que la captura de una `url` de un `QR` (`rawResult.getText()`) en un `fragment`, se abra en un `WebView` que tengo en un `activity`.

He intentado de todo, he leído tutoriales, foros y no he dado con la respuesta.

**Fragment**:

```
@Override
public void handleResult(Result rawResult) {
    try {
        Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), notification);
        r.play();
    } catch (Exception e) {}

    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(rawResult.getText()));
    startActivity(browserIntent);

}
```

**Activity con WebView**:

```
public void handlerwebview(View view){

    myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvschv);
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

    myWebView.loadUrl(rawResult.getText());
}
```

La idea es que al leer el `código QR` (tipo `url`), se abra automáticamente un `activity` y la `url` se cargue en el `WebView`.

Espero me puedan ayudar, no sé que más hacer, intente con `Bundle`, con `Intent` y no funciono.

Comment: Lo que estas necesitando es pasar la url como parametro al Activity que contriene la webView. Aca te dejo un link donde se explica como pasar parametros a un Activity.
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36902/como-enviar-datos-entre-activities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En realidad lo que deseas es enviar información desde una Activity a otra

[¿Como enviar datos entre activities?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36902/como-enviar-datos-entre-activities)

En el caso de tu pregunta, lo puedes realizar de esta forma

```
   Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityDestino.class);
   //Agrega url de QR
   intent.putExtra("url_qr", rawResult.getText());
   //Inicia Intent para abrir activity destino
   startActivity(intent);
```

Con respecto a tu comentario:

> Espero me puedan ayudar, no se que más hacer, intente con Bundle, con
>   Intent, y no funciono.

**Es muy importante mencionar que la recepción de la información en la `Activity` destino debe realizarse dentro del método `onCreate()` de la `Activity`.**

```
private String urlQR = "";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
...
...
  Bundle parametros = this.getIntent().getExtras();
  if(parametros !=null){
     //Obtiene valor de la url 
     urlQR = parametros.getString("url_qr");         
  } 
...
...
}
```

al obtener el valor, este puedes usarlo en tu clase sin problema:

```
public void handlerwebview(View view){

    myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvschv);
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

    myWebView.loadUrl(urlQR);
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Todo bien hasta ahí, pero al ejecutar, se realiza la lectura del código qr, pero al entrar al activity con el webview, la aplicación se cierra. :'(

Comment: Es importante revisar el LogCat, que mensaje de error muestra?

Comment: debes poner breakpoints para poder debuggear