# Cómo capturar los Id de cada elemento de un Spinner

Tags: php, mysql, android-studio, json

Hola amigos saben como realizar una captura de los id de cada sucursal que me muestra mi spinner? y mostrarlo en otra actividad, por ahora estoy mostrando solo el nombre de las sucursales, pero en remplazo de eso quiero el id se me muestre ya no el nombre. ayuda por favor

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//uno


EditText edtPassword;
Button btnLogin;
String sucursal,usuario, password;

//dos

List<String> listaIdSucursales; //guarda el id de la sucursal
List<String> listaSucursales; //guarda el nombre de la sucursal
List<String> listaDepartamentos;
Spinner spinnerSucursales,spinnerDepartamentos;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    spinnerSucursales = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_sucursales);
    spinnerDepartamentos = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_departamentos);
    edtPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtPassword);
    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

    recuperarPreferencia();
    cargarSucursales();

    spinnerSucursales.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String sucursal = spinnerSucursales.getSelectedItem().toString();
            for (int i = 0; i < listaIdSucursales.size(); i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < listaSucursales.size(); j++) {
                    if (sucursal == listaSucursales.get(i)) {
                        String idsucursal = listaIdSucursales.get(i);
                        cargarDepartamentos(idsucursal);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            sucursal=spinnerSucursales.getSelectedItem().toString();
            usuario=spinnerDepartamentos.getSelectedItem().toString();
            password=edtPassword.getText().toString();
            if (!usuario.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()){
                validarUsuario("http://192.168.43.91:8888/Tutoriales/spinnerDependienteAndroid/php/login.php");
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"No se permiten campos vacios",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
 }
  private void validarUsuario(String URL){
    StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            if (!response.isEmpty()){
                guardarPreferencias();
                Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Principal.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();


                Intent intent1=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Principal.class);
                intent.putExtra("sucursal",sucursal);
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);

            }else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"usuario o contraseña incorrecta",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener(){
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"ERROR",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams()throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String>parametros=new HashMap<String,String>();
           parametros.put("sucursal",sucursal);
            parametros.put("usuario",usuario);
            parametros.put("password",password);
            return parametros;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
 }
  private void guardarPreferencias(){
    SharedPreferences preferences=getSharedPreferences("preferenciaLogin", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=preferences.edit();
   editor.putString("sucursal",sucursal);
    editor.putString("usuario",usuario);
    editor.putString("password",password);
    editor.putBoolean("sesion",true);
    editor.commit();
 }
  private void recuperarPreferencia(){
    SharedPreferences preferences=getSharedPreferences("preferenciaLogin", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    edtPassword.setText(preferences.getString("password",""));
 }

// dos
public void cargarSucursales(){
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String url = "http://192.168.43.91:8888/Tutoriales/spinnerDependienteAndroid/php/Metodos.php?funcion=obtenerSucursales";

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            if(response.length() > 0){
                try{
                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                    obtenerSucursales(jsonArray);
                }catch(JSONException jsnex1){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),jsnex1.toString()
                            ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    queue.add(stringRequest);
}

public void obtenerSucursales(JSONArray jsonArray){
    listaIdSucursales = new ArrayList<String>();
    listaSucursales = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
        try{
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            //display
            String idsucursal = jsonObject.getString("idsucursal");
            //String direccion = jsonObject.getString("idsucursal");
            String direccion = jsonObject.getString("direccion");
            listaIdSucursales.add(idsucursal);
            listaSucursales.add(direccion);



        }catch(JSONException jsnEx2){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),jsnEx2.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterSucursales = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,listaSucursales);
    spinnerSucursales.setAdapter(adapterSucursales);
}

public void cargarDepartamentos(String idsucursal){
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String url = "http://192.168.43.91:8888/Tutoriales/spinnerDependienteAndroid/php/Metodos.php?funcion=obtenerDepartamentos&id_sucursal="+idsucursal;

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            if(response.length() > 0){
                try{
                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                    obtenerDepartamentos(jsonArray);
                }catch(JSONException jsnEx4){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),jsnEx4.toString(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error: "+error.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    queue.add(stringRequest);
}

public void obtenerDepartamentos(JSONArray jsonArray){
    listaDepartamentos = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
        try{
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String usuario = jsonObject.getString("usuario");
            listaDepartamentos.add(usuario);
        }catch(JSONException jsnEx5){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),jsnEx5.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterDepartamentos = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,listaDepartamentos);
    spinnerDepartamentos.setAdapter(adapterDepartamentos);
}
```

}
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si tienes una lista de ids de sucursales,

```
List<String> listaIdSucursales;
```

puedes obtener el id de la sucursal en base a el indice del elemento seleccionado en tu Spinner, usando el método `getSelectedItemPosition()` y de esta forma obtener el id de la lista `listaIdSucursales`:

```
//Obtiene posicion en Spinner.
int posicionSpinner = spinnerSucursales.getSelectedItemPosition();
//Obtiene id de Sucursal.
int idSucursal = listaIdSucursales.get(posicionSpinner);

Intent intent1=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Principal.class);
//intent.putExtra("sucursal",sucursal);
intent.putExtra("idSucursal",idSucursal);
MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
```

Para enviar y recibir datos entre Actividades revisa:

[¿Como enviar datos entre activities?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36902/como-enviar-datos-entre-activities/36924#36924)

Comment: lo reviso ahora

Comment: gracias funciono a la perfecion

Comment: Excelente, saludos Willy!

Comment: amigo disculpa no me percate del problema al poner este Intent intent1=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Principal.class);
//intent.putExtra("sucursal",sucursal);
intent.putExtra("idSucursal",idSucursal);
MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent); automaticamente inicia sesion