# Pasar de actividad Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase

vereis, en un RecyclerView hecho con Firebase, quiero que al pinchar en alguna de las card_views dirija al usuario a otra activity con los detalles. ¿Como puedo hacer ese cambio de actividad?
Os enseño mi clase. Si es posible me gustaría usar el linear layout como botón.
Os pongo en situación, trata de una lista de restaurantes y al pinchas en uno quiero que me lleve a los detalles de ese restaurante. Entonces tengo que ir a una actividad con los detalles y pasarle algunos valores desde el recycled view como el nombre.

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<Discoteca> discotecas;

MyAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Discoteca> p){
    context = c;
    discotecas = p;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new MyViewHolder((LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.discoteca_card, parent, false)));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    //RecyclerView
    holder.nombre.setText(discotecas.get(position).getName());
    holder.zona.setText(discotecas.get(position).getZona());
    Picasso.get().load(discotecas.get(position).getFoto()).into(holder.foto_discoteca);

    //Pagina Details
    //holder.ubicacion.setText(discotecas.get(position).getUbicacion());


}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return discotecas.size();
}

static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView nombre, zona;
    ImageView foto_discoteca;

    //Vainas Details Page
    LinearLayout parentLayout;
    TextView ubicacion;

    MyViewHolder(View itemView){
        super(itemView);
        nombre = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nombreClub);
        zona = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.zonaClub);
        foto_discoteca = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.id_imagen);

        //Details Page
        parentLayout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.linear_id);

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dentro de `onBindViewHolder()` puedes configurar un listener a la vista que deseas, y dentro de su mètodo `onClick()` configuras que cargue otra Activity:

```
@Override

    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        //RecyclerView
        holder.nombre.setText(discotecas.get(position).getName());
        holder.zona.setText(discotecas.get(position).getZona());
        Picasso.get().load(discotecas.get(position).getFoto()).into(holder.foto_discoteca);

        //Pagina Details
        //holder.ubicacion.setText(discotecas.get(position).getUbicacion());

          holder.nombre.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

               //Abre otra Activity.
               Intent intent = new Intent(context, YOUR_ACTIVITY.class);
               intent.putExtra("zona", discotecas.get(position).getZona()); 
               context.startActivity(intent)

            }
        });


    }
```

---

Para recibirlo en otra Activity lo realizarias de esta forma:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ...
    ...
    Bundle parametros = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    if(parametros !=null){
      String datoRecibido = parametros.getString("zona"); 
      //Lo agrega a un TextView.
      myTextView.setText(datoRecibido);
    } 

}
```

Te sugiero revisar:

[¿Como enviar datos entre activities?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36902/como-enviar-datos-entre-activities)

Comment: funciona perfectamente gracias! Una pregunta, y si quisiera pasar un dato como este `holder.zona.setText(discotecas.get(position).getZona());` como lo haria? A la otra activity me refiero

Comment: Si lo deseas enviar a la activity puedes usar el intent, por ejemplo ese valor enviarlo de esta forma :  intent.putExtra("zona", discotecas.get(position).getZona());     Revisa esta respuesta. https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/36924/95 , no olvides marcar como soluciòn las respuestas que ayuden a solucionar el problema planteado en la pregunta, revisa [tour], saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda de verdad, al realizar eso, como podria hacerlo para recoger ese dato en otra actividad y ponerlo en un Textview?

Comment: Aqui se muestra tambien es.stackoverflow.com/a/36924/95 , dentro de onCreate lo obtienes, agregue un ejemplo en la respuesta, revisa nuevamente,  saludos.