# Pasar datos entre Actividades sin cambiar de Actividad

Tags: android, activity, android-intent, studio, datos

tengo el siguiente problemilla en Android Studio:

Si tengo las Actividades **a**, **b** y **c**, y en la actividad **c** recibo
un valor que quiero pasarle a la actividad **a** y **b**, para que éstas lo  almacenen, pero no quiero salir en ningún momento de la actividad **c**.
¿Cómo logro esto?

Es posible que sea una pregunta muy estúpida, pero estoy embarullado.
Gracias!

Comment: Bienvenido, Ya existe información acerca de esto en el sitio : https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36902/como-enviar-datos-entre-activities  te sugerimos revisar en el sitio. Para enviar datos usas un bundle en un Intent.

Comment: Infinitas gracias, pero no encontré en ninguna de las respuestas lo que estoy buscando. Porque para pasar un bundle tengo que usar startActivity(), que me manda a la actividad donde estoy enviando los datos, y es lo que quiero evitar.

Comment: Puedes usar SharedPreferences para acceder a los datos desde cualquier activity, fragment o service

Comment: si quieres compartir datos con otras pantallas puedes crear una caché con un repositorio singleton y que las otras actividades recuperen de ahí los datos cuando los necesiten.  Otra opción es que ese repositorio sea observable y que la activity reaccione a los cambios... puedes hacerlo a través de un Presenter o ViewModel.

Comment: Muchas gracias, estoy probando cuàl solucion me conviene màs

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar uno de estos dos métodos:

1. Implementar una interface
2. Implementar viewmodel

Pero como estoy entendiendo tu descripción, deberías tener una clase separada que se encargue solo de almacenar datos y puedas reutilizarla (me imagino que estás usando shared preferences) le podríamos llamar **PreferencesManager**, recomiendo que comprendas primero [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7491287/android-how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-non-activity-class) y después te pases a este [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39573213/how-to-create-a-sharedpreference-class-in-android)

Comment: Sì, eso debí hacer en un principio, pero ahora estoy terminando la app y deberìa modificar demasiadas cosas :D Gracias.