# Aplicacion se detiene Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Buen día, mi aplicacion se detiene al undir el boton siguiente en el activity main al pasar al activity_datos. Este es el error que me muestra en el logcat. Disculpen si he pegado mal el codigo, es mi primera vez :(

12-31 22:38:49.636 8208-8208/sergio.com.datos E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: sergio.com.datos, PID: 8208
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{sergio.com.datos/sergio.com.datos.Datos}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2474)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2544)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:163)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1367)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5608)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1397)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1192)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
at sergio.com.datos.Datos.onCreate(Datos.java:23)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5993)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1111)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2427)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2544) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:163) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1367) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5608) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1397) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1192)

Codigo xml Main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/tvEmail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="33dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="34dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Email"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tvDescripcion"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvTelefono" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/tvTelefono"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Telefono"
    android:inputType="phone"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tvEmail"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tvEmail"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvFecha" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/tvNombre"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Nombre Completo"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tvFecha"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bSiguiente"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:onClick="siguiente"
    android:text="@string/bSiguiente"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/ibFecha"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tvNombre"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvDescripcion" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/tvFecha"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="39dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="39dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="21dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Formato Fecha"
    android:inputType="date"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tvTelefono"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/ibFecha"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvNombre" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ibFecha"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="17dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tvFecha"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tvFecha"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tvFecha"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_my_calendar" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/tvDescripcion"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="41dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="start|top"
    android:hint="Descripcion"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bSiguiente"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/bSiguiente"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tvEmail"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvEmail" />

Activity_datos xml 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Datos">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cTelefono"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:text="@string/cTelefono"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/cFecha"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cFecha" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cNombre"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="63dp"
    android:text="@string/cNombre"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/cEmail"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/cEmail"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cFecha"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:text="@string/cFecha"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/cNombre"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cNombre" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cEmail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
    android:text="@string/cEmail"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/cDescripcion"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/cDescripcion"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cTelefono" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cDescripcion"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="44dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="44dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
    android:text="@string/cDescripcion"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cEmail" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bEditar"
    android:layout_width="202dp"
    android:layout_height="46dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="83dp"
    android:onClick="volver"
    android:text="@string/beditar"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cDescripcion" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Datos.java

```
package sergio.com.datos;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class Datos extends AppCompatActivity {
private TextView cNombre;
private TextView cFecha;
private TextView cTelefono;
private TextView cEmail;
private TextView cDescripcion;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_datos);

    Bundle parametros= getIntent().getExtras();
    assert parametros != null;
    String nombre=parametros.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.cNombre),"nombre");
    String telefono=parametros.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.cTelefono),"telefono");
    String email=parametros.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.cEmail),"email");
    String fecha=parametros.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.cFecha),"fecha");
    String descripcion=parametros.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.cDescripcion),"descripcion");
    cNombre=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.cNombre);
    cTelefono=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.cTelefono);
    cEmail=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.cEmail);
    cFecha=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.cFecha);
    cDescripcion=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.cDescripcion);

    cNombre.setText(nombre);
    cTelefono.setText(telefono);
    cEmail.setText(email);
    cFecha.setText(fecha);
    cDescripcion.setText(descripcion);

}
public void volver(View button) {

    Intent j = new Intent(Datos.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(j);
}
```

}

MainActivity java

```
package sergio.com.datos;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
public void siguiente (View button) {

    Intent i= new Intent (MainActivity.this,Datos.class);
    EditText tvNombre=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.tvNombre);
    EditText tvFecha=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.tvFecha) ;
    EditText tvTelefono=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.tvTelefono) ;
    EditText tvEmail=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.tvEmail) ;
    EditText tvDescripcion=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.tvDescripcion) ;
    getIntent().putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.cNombre),tvNombre.getText().toString());
    getIntent().putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.cFecha),tvFecha.getText().toString());
    getIntent().putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.cTelefono),tvTelefono.getText().toString());
    getIntent().putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.cEmail),tvEmail.getText().toString());
    getIntent().putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.cDescripcion),tvDescripcion.getText().toString());
    startActivity(i);

}
```

}

Comment: Hola Sergio en realidad el problema se debe a que estas enviando incorrectamente los datos al realizar el Intent, revisa https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36902/como-enviar-datos-entre-activities agregue respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error se describe aqui:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
> method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String,
> java.lang.String)' on a null object reference at
> sergio.com.datos.Datos.onCreate(Datos.java:23)

y se encuentra en el metodo `onCreate()` de la clase `Datos.java`, el o los valores que recibes en el bundle tienen valor `null`,  puedes considerar inicialmente una validaciòn:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_datos);

    Bundle parametros= getIntent().getExtras();
    assert parametros != null;

    if(parametros != null){ //Validacion...
   
    String nombre=parametros.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.cNombre),"nombre");
    String telefono=parametros.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.cTelefono),"telefono");
    String email=parametros.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.cEmail),"email");
    String fecha=parametros.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.cFecha),"fecha");
    String descripcion=parametros.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.cDescripcion),"descripcion");
    cNombre=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.cNombre);
    cTelefono=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.cTelefono);
    cEmail=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.cEmail);
    cFecha=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.cFecha);
    cDescripcion=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.cDescripcion);

    cNombre.setText(nombre);
    cTelefono.setText(telefono);
    cEmail.setText(email);
    cFecha.setText(fecha);
    cDescripcion.setText(descripcion);

    } 

}
```

**Pero la razòn por la cual llega con valor null es porque no agregas correctamente los datos a enviar al `Intent`**, realizalo de esta forma:

```
public void siguiente (View button) {

    Intent i= new Intent (MainActivity.this,Datos.class);
    EditText tvNombre=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.tvNombre);
    EditText tvFecha=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.tvFecha) ;
    EditText tvTelefono=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.tvTelefono) ;
    EditText tvEmail=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.tvEmail) ;
    EditText tvDescripcion=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.tvDescripcion) ;
    i.putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.cNombre),tvNombre.getText().toString());
    i.putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.cFecha),tvFecha.getText().toString());
    i.putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.cTelefono),tvTelefono.getText().toString());
    i.putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.cEmail),tvEmail.getText().toString());
    i.putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.cDescripcion),tvDescripcion.getText().toString());
    startActivity(i);

}
```

Revisa:

[¿Como enviar datos entre activities?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36902/como-enviar-datos-entre-activities)

Comment: Estimado amigo, esto solucionó mi problema . Muchas gracias por tomarse el tiempo de revisar mi pregunta.

Comment: Excelente que pudiste solucionar el problema, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que te recomendaría es que uses nombres a tus widgets que sean adecuados; por ejemplo, el usar el prefijo tv... da la idea de que es un TextView del que estamos hablando; en cambio si renombraras tus EditText con el prefijo, por ejemplo, et... te darían mas sentido, pero sólo es una recomendación.

En cuanto al error que describes, creo que no estas seteando los extras de manera correcta, ya que si tu intent es **i** entonces lo correcto sería i.putExtra(KEY,VALUE).

Te comparto un ejemplo de como sería correcto:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CobroDeCuenta.this, DetalleImagen.class);
            intent.putExtra(DetalleImagen.EXTRA_PARAM_SUCURSAL, sucursal);
            intent.putExtra(DetalleImagen.EXTRA_PARAM_ANO, ano);
            intent.putExtra(DetalleImagen.EXTRA_PARAM_FOLIO_VENTA, folioVenta);
            intent.putExtra(DetalleImagen.EXTRA_PARAM_TIPO_IMAGEN, Constantes.FOTO_DEL_CLIENTE);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Estimado Marcos, estoy de acuerdo con la forma de nombrar los widgets. Muchas gracias por el comentario y por tomarte el tiempo de revisar mi pregunta :)