# ¿Cómo pasar datos de un public void a otro?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Tengo dos dudas, tengo mi archivo java de la siguiente manera:

```
Public class PrimerActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

}
```

Todo está en un mismo Activity

**Pregunta 1**: Como paso un dato de un `public void A(quiero enviar 3 datos-variables)` al `public void B(Recibe los 3 datos -variables para ser usadas )`.

**Pregunta 2**: Como puedo llamar al `public void B(variable 1,variable 2, variable 3)` dentro del `Public class PrimerActivity extends AppCompatActivity`.

Comment: Te refieres a enviar datos entre activities??: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36902/como-enviar-datos-entre-activities

Comment: No, todo es un mismo Activity

Comment: Fácil, no los hagas void. Un void es una función que literalmente no devuelve *NADA* (Void = vacío). Haz que la función devuelva lo que necesitas y en la que necesites su valor simplemente tienes que invocarla. Si no, pues puedes usar variables de clase, es decir, en tu `Activity` define las 3 variables que quieres usar en los métodos... pero es un poco inútil hacer eso si solo los vas a usar dentro de esos métodos, estarían mejor como parámetros de las funciones

Comment: entonces lago asi ? ///////////  publico o private double A(){ aqui obtengo  los valores double r,g,b esos 3 double los usare en B} y donde las quiero usar como seria otro public/private dolube o ya seria void B(double r,double g,double b){ este void color ya lo estaria llamando en mi Public class} – JUAN MIGUEL DIAZ HERNANDEZ hace 9 minutos    Eliminar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acuerdo a lo que comentas:

"`A()` aqui obtengo los valores double r,g,b esos 3 double los usare en `B()`"

Lo puedes realizar de esta forma,

```
Public class PrimerActivity extends AppCompatActivity{


    public void A(String variable1, String variable2, String variable3){

       //Obtiene valores que se usaran en B().

        //Envia valores a método B()
        this.B(variable1, variable2, variable3);
    }

    public void B(String variable1, String variable2, String variable3){
        
          //Recibe valores definidos en B().        

    }

}
```

Comment: Gracias, por tomarte tu tiempo