# Pasar datos con un intent en Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Hola estoy empezando en android studio y intento pasar unas variables ente diferentes activity la cosa es que al pasar de la main_ activity a la segunda funciona perfectamente pera al pasarlo de la 2 a la 3 no funciona. No me da ningún error simplemente no pasa la variable.

Aquí podéis ver el código que uso para pasarlo y para recibir las variables (use el mismo código en las dos solo cambiando las activity a las que hace referencia en intent)

```
public void onClick(View view) {
       Intent pasaTiempo = new Intent(RepActivity.this, TimeActivity.class);
       pasaTiempo.putExtra("min", minutos);
       pasaTiempo.putExtra("sec", seconds);
       startActivity(pasaTiempo);
            }
```

Donde se recibe

```
bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
     int minutos2 = bundle.getInt("min");
     int seconds2 = bundle.getInt("sec");
```

No hay error al decir cual es la activity a la que tiene que pasar ya que si que cambia la pantalla

Comment: Hola, en la segunda actividad estás añadiendo los parámetros que recuperas de la primera? Me da la impresión de que recuperas los datos en variables locales, y después en el método onClick estás pasando valores que igual no tienes inicializados.

Answer (score 4):

tu còdigo es correcto, pero lo importante aquì es donde se reciben los datos, de acuerdo a tu Intent se envían a la Activity llamada `TimeActivity` pero aquì debes asegurar se obtengan ùnicamente dentro del mètodo onCreate() de otra forma no podràs obtener los valores:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        int minutos2 = bundle.getInt("min");
        int seconds2 = bundle.getInt("sec");

        
    }
}
```

pero de esta forma solo los podràs usar dentro de este mètodo, puedes crear variables de clase para que los valores puedan ser leidos en toda tu clase:

```
private int minutos2;
private int segundos2;

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
            bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
            minutos2 = bundle.getInt("min");
            seconds2 = bundle.getInt("sec");
    
            
        }
    }
```

Te sugiero revisar tambièn :

[¿Como enviar datos entre activities?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36902/como-enviar-datos-entre-activities)

Comment: En efecro el problema era que no estaba en el onCreate ahora funciona perfectamente

Comment: Excelente @PedroFernándezMuñoz , solo recuerda votar y marcar como soluciòn si esta publicaciòn ayudo a solucionar el problema planteado en la pregunta, revisa [tour], saludos.