# ¿Como encryptar por completo shared_preferences en android?

Tags: android, encriptación, sharedpreferences

Lo que estoy intentando hacer es encryptar todos los archivos que se guardan en la carpeta shared_preferences de mi app android, mi problema es que en la documentacion https://developer.android.com/topic/security/data#java no explica como hacer para encryptar los archivos sin necesidad de poner los valores dentro del MainActivity.java, otra cosa que no entiendo es porque cuando encrypto los datos me crea un archivo con los datos encryptados y el otro archivo donde estan los datos reales sigue estando. ¿esto esta bien?,¿tiene sentido que hayan 2 archivos, uno con los datos reales y otro con los datos encryptados?
adjunto codigo con los valores editados a modo de ejemplo:
MainActivity.java

```
String encrypt = null;
try {
  encrypt = MasterKeys.getOrCreate(MasterKeys.AES256_GCM_SPEC);
} catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}

SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = null;
try {
  sharedPreferences = EncryptedSharedPreferences.create(
          "swrve encrypt",
          encrypt,
          this,
          EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefKeyEncryptionScheme.AES256_SIV,
          EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefValueEncryptionScheme.AES256_GCM
  );
} catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}

// Guardo los datos encriptandolos en Shared Preferences
sharedPreferences.edit()
        .putString("swrve_cr_flush_delay", "3092")
        .putString("userId", "asghdj23-21asdda-23dsacv")
        .putString("trackingState", "going")
        .putString("swrve_cr_flush_frequency", "600")
        .apply();
```

}

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. ¿Cuál es el problema concretamente? ¿Si no quieres poner los datos en el código que usarás para encriptarlos, dónde quieres ponerlos o de dónde piensas sacar esos datos? Para facilitar cualquier ayuda considera poner siempre el código como texto, no en capturas de imagen.

Comment: No te acostumbres a poner imágenes del código, es una mala praxis que tiende a rechazar la atención sobre la misma. Si alguien desea estuiar tu caso, le obligas a reescribir de nuevo todo el código. Acostumbra a copiar el mismo en tu pregunta haciendo un ciopia pega. Un saludo y suerte

Comment: borre las imagenes y puse el codigo, @A.Cedano mi problema concretamente es, viste que en el main activity yo estoy poniendo los datos q quiero encryptar, bueno en lugar de poner los datos, se puede poner el nombre del archivo que quiero encryptar? y en el caso de no ser posible, sirve de algo encryptar esos datos si de igual manera van a estar expuestos en el mainactivity?

Comment: Si necesitas encriptar los datos de shared preferences, echa un vistazo a EncryptedSharedPreferences https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/security/crypto/EncryptedSharedPreferences

Answer (score 0):

Al usar la clase `EncryptedSharedPreferences` en realidad tiene el mismo funcionamiento que la clase `SharedPreferences` pero en este caso encripta automáticamente  sus llaves y valores utilizando un método de dos esquemas.

El nombre del archivo de preferencias lo defines como el primer parámetro del método `.create()` de `EncryptedSharedPreferences` no necesitas crear otro archivo :

```
EncryptedSharedPreferences.create("secret_shared_prefs",....
```

En cuanto a tu pregunta:

> ¿sirve de algo encryptar esos datos si de igual manera van a estar
> expuestos en el mainactivity?

Los valores los recibes en tu Activity, puede ser por ejemplo desde una petición a un WS o simplemente que estos se envíen desde otra Activity, ejemplo:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class)
intent.putExtra("swrve_cr_flush_delay", "3092")
intent.putExtra("trackingState", "going")
intent.putExtra("swrve_cr_flush_frequency", "600")
startActivity(intent);
```

Entonces en tu `MainActivity` los recibirías dentro de `onCreate()` y los guardarías de esta forma:

```
  Bundle parametros = this.getIntent().getExtras();
   
   if(parametros !=null){
     // Guardo los datos encriptandolos en Shared Preferences 
     sharedPreferences.edit()
    .putString("swrve_cr_flush_delay", parametros.getString("swrve_cr_flush_delay"))
    .putString("userId", parametros.getString("userId"))
    .putString("trackingState", parametros.getString("trackingState"))
    .putString("swrve_cr_flush_frequency", parametros.getString("swrve_cr_flush_frequency"))
    .apply();
   }
```

Revisa:

[Como enviar datos entre Actividades.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36902/como-enviar-datos-entre-activities/36924#36924)