# Las variables "Session" o "extras" son de único uso?

Tags: java, android

hice una [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/567501/se-cierra-la-app-cuando-cambio-a-un-fragment-despues-de-hacer-una-modificacion) anteriormente, y luego de investigar un poco el problema, decidi debuggear denuevo la aplicacion y noté que las variables de "Session" o "extras", están llegando nulls, no sé porque si no le digo que borren sus valores.

Las variables son ingresadas cuando el usuario que quiere entrar pone bien su mail y contraseña. Desde la Base de datos trae todo lo necesario y los paso del Login al Menu Principal:

```
 if(u != null){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Bienvenido/a " + u.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent menu = new Intent(this, MenuPrincipal.class);
                menu.putExtra("id", u.getId());
                menu.putExtra("userName", u.getName());
                menu.putExtra("usersurname", u.getSurname());
                menu.putExtra("userage", u.getAge());
                menu.putExtra("userDni", u.getDni());
                menu.putExtra("userheight", u.getHeight());
                menu.putExtra("usersex", u.getSex());
                menu.putExtra("userpassword", u.getPassword());
                menu.putExtra("userweight", u.getWeight());
                menu.putExtra("useremail", u.getEmail());
                menu.putExtra("usertargetBody", u.getTargetBody());
                menu.putExtra("usertargetDietas", u.getTargetDiet());

                startActivity(menu);
```

Y luego los uso en 1 solo Fragment, no los utilizo en ningun otro lugar:

```
String nombreUsuario = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("userName");
        String apellidoUsuario = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("usersurname");
        Integer dniUsuario = getActivity().getIntent().getIntExtra("userDni", u.getDni());
        String contraseniaUsuario = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("userpassword");
        Integer pesoUsuario = getActivity().getIntent().getIntExtra("userweight", u.getWeight());
        Integer alturaUsuario = getActivity().getIntent().getIntExtra("userheight", u.getHeight());
        String sexoUsuario = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("usersex");
        String mailUsuario = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("useremail");
        Integer edadUsuario = getActivity().getIntent().getIntExtra("userage", u.getAge());
        Integer objetivoCorporalUsuario = getActivity().getIntent().getIntExtra("usertargetBody", u.getTargetBody());
        Integer objetivoDietaUsuario = getActivity().getIntent().getIntExtra("usertargetDietas", u.getTargetDiet());
```

Mi pregunta es, si los `menu.putExtra()` y `getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra()`, son de único uso? Si los asigno a una variable, los `getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra()` pierden su valor?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No deben perder su valor, me parece que el problema aquí es que los estás tratando de recibir en un Fragment y no en una Activity, agregué una respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

**No deben perder su valor, me parece que el problema aquí es que los estás tratando de recibir en un `Fragment` ( debido a que usas `getActivity()` ), para recibirlos adecuadamente, debes recibirlos en una `Activity`.**

Estás definiendo enviar varios valores a través de un `bundle` desde una `Activity` a la clase `MenuPrincipal.class` la cual debe ser una Activity.

**Si estás enviando los valores a la clase, para que se reciban correctamente debes recibirlos dentro de onCreate() de tu Activity**:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String nombreUsuario = this.getIntent().getStringExtra("userName");
        String apellidoUsuario = 
        this.getIntent().getStringExtra("usersurname");
        Integer dniUsuario = this.getIntent().getIntExtra("userDni", u.getDni());
        String contraseniaUsuario = 
        this.getIntent().getStringExtra("userpassword");
        Integer pesoUsuario = this.getIntent().getIntExtra("userweight", u.getWeight());
        Integer alturaUsuario = this.getIntent().getIntExtra("userheight", u.getHeight());
        String sexoUsuario = this.getIntent().getStringExtra("usersex");
        String mailUsuario = this.getIntent().getStringExtra("useremail");
        Integer edadUsuario = this.getIntent().getIntExtra("userage", u.getAge());
        Integer objetivoCorporalUsuario = 
        this.getIntent().getIntExtra("usertargetBody", u.getTargetBody());
        Integer objetivoDietaUsuario = 
        this.getIntent().getIntExtra("usertargetDietas", u.getTargetDiet());




}
```

Revisa esta respuesta:

**[¿Como enviar datos entre activities?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36902/como-enviar-datos-entre-activities)**