# Quiero que salgo un tipo de imagen segun la variable recibida en Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

Desde un activity main envio un texto con un intent a otro activity y segun la palabra que salga (supongo que es con un if) me gustaria que la imagen sea una u otra.
Por ejemplo si eres tauro, que salga una imagen de tauro
Esto lo que envia el main:

```
 public void sendMessage(View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        
        if(mes==2){
            if(dia<=18){
                horoscopo="Acuario";
            }
            else{
                horoscopo="Piscis";
            }
        }




        EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Nombre);
        String message1 = editText1.getText().toString();
        String message2 = horoscopo;
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message1 + ", tu signo del zodiaco es: " + message2);


        startActivity(intent);


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Te sugiero inicialmente revisar:

**[¿Cómo enviar datos entre activities?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36902/c%c3%b3mo-enviar-datos-entre-activities)**

Para enviar el dato desde la Activity inicial, realizalo de esta forma, donde `horoscopo` contiene el valor a enviar:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
...
...
intent.putExtra("valor_horoscopo", horoscopo);
startActivity(intent);
```

en la `Activity` destino `DisplayMessageActivity.class`, recibe el valor y mediante un `switch` puedes decidir que imagen cargar:

```
private String myhoroscopo = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //* Obtiene el valor del horoscopo.
    Bundle parametros = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    if(parametros !=null){
        myhoroscopo = parametros.getString("valor_horoscopo"); 
    } 

    //* Define que imagen cargar       
    switch (myhoroscopo) {
    case "Acuario":
        //* Carga imagen. 
        break;
    case "Piscis":
        //* Carga imagen. 
        break; 
    case "Tauro":
        //* Carga imagen. 
        break;

     default:
        //* No carga imagen.
         
    }


}
```