# Tengo 4 activities, cuando quiero regresar del cuarto al segundo envío ciertos datos pero al iniciar el segundo activity de nuevo estos datos se borr

Tags: java, android-studio, android-intent, null, android-toast

Cuarto activity

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menufinal){
    switch(menufinal.getItemId()){
        case R.id.regresar:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), usuario, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), contra, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent ticketMain = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
            ticketMain.putExtra("UsuarioBack",usuario);
            ticketMain.putExtra("ContraBack",contra);
            ticketMain.putExtra("prueba",prueba);
            ticketMain.putExtra("nuEfectivo",nuEfectivo);
            ticketMain.putExtra("nuTarjeta",nuTarjeta);
            startActivity(ticketMain);
            break;
        case R.id.cerrar:
            txtTicket.setText("");
            finishAffinity();
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(menufinal);
}
```

Segundo Activity, aqui el toast imprime los datos recibidos del cuarto activity pero mágicamente se convierten a null pese a que antes de enviarlos en el cuarto activity los valide con un toast y efectivamente tienen Datos

```
    //Variables de cuarto activity
    usuarioPago=mainProgramadores.getString("UsuarioBack");
    contraPago=mainProgramadores.getString("ContraBack");
    prueba=mainProgramadores.getString("prueba");
    nuEfectivo=mainProgramadores.getInt("nuEfectivo");
    nuTarjeta=mainProgramadores.getInt("nuTarjeta");
        if(prueba!=null){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+contraPago, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+usuarioPago, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: No estás mostrando en qué punto exactamente se convierten en null. Además sigue la traza del código para ver si en el recorrido los datos son modificados.

Comment: Hola Gustavo, considerando que "mágicamente se convierten a null" no es una causa probable, se me ocurre que tal vez, en algún lugar de tu código, estés reinicinado un objeto, algo como **mainProgramadores = new MainProgramadores();** , que dejaría sin inicializar los atributos... es solo una conjetura.

Answer (score 0):

Para recibir tus variables y asegurar que no tengan valores `null` en la `Activity` destino, **debes asegurar siempre obtener los datos en el método `onCreate()` de la Activity**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ...
    ...
    //Recibe valores
    usuarioPago=mainProgramadores.getString("UsuarioBack");
    contraPago=mainProgramadores.getString("ContraBack");
    prueba=mainProgramadores.getString("prueba");
    nuEfectivo=mainProgramadores.getInt("nuEfectivo");
    nuTarjeta=mainProgramadores.getInt("nuTarjeta");
     ...
     ...
        
    }
}
```

Te sugiero revisar:

[¿Cómo enviar datos entre activities?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36902/c%C3%B3mo-enviar-datos-entre-activities)