# Pasar datos entre dos fragmentos

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragment

Estoy haciendo un `Navigation Draw Activity`, con `fragments` dentro. El caso es que tengo varios fragmentos. Es un formulario largo que lo dividí en varios fragments, y quiero enviar los datos que reciba de un `editText` del primer fragmentm, obtenerlos en el siguiente fragmento. Estoy usando `bundles`, ya lo había usado en activities pero en fragments es distinto. El punto es que cuando pruebo mi aplicación, cuando llego al fragment donde en teoría debería recibir los datos.

La aplicación se cierra y muestra el siguiente mensaje de error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Les comparto parte de mi código, no se que estoy haciendo mal. ***Cabe resaltar que el objetivo de pasar los datos de un fragment a otro***, es que en ese ultimo fragment recibir datos de varios fragments y luego insertarlo en una BD.

Fragment donde envio el dato:

```
  bSiguiente.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {





            /*Bundle data = new Bundle();
            data.putString("folio", folio.getText().toString());

            FragmentTransaction t = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();
            SherlockListFragment mFrag = new ProfileFragment();
            mFrag.setArguments(data);
            t.replace(R.id.main_frag, mFrag);
            t.commit();*/

            Bundle data = new Bundle();
            data.putString("userprofile", folio.getText().toString());
            FragmentTransaction t = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();
            CapturarInstalaciones6Fragment mFrag = new CapturarInstalaciones6Fragment();
            mFrag.setArguments(data);

            t.commit();
```

Fragment donde deberia recibir el dato (lo muestro en un Toast para probarlo):

```
 bSiguiente.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Bundle extras = getArguments();
            String s = extras.getString("userprofile");
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Folio: "+ s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            FragmentTransaction trans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            trans.replace(R.id.contenedor, new CapturarInstalaciones7Fragment());
            trans.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
            trans.addToBackStack(null);
            trans.commit();

        }
    });
```

Comment: Esta pregunta esta duplicada, considero que si revisas esta respuesta tendras una solución a su problema. https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/5725/66554

Comment: Hola. Ya lo habia revisado con anterioridad y he probado, pero siguen sin funcionarme.

Comment: Javier es que estas sacando los datos según entiendo de esta manera: `Bundle extras = getArguments();` esto dentro del evento onClick. El post que te pasé dice que lo hagas en el onCreate del fragment. Has las validaciones que el bundle no este null, los extras he incluso pregunta si los extras tienen la llave que necesitas (...getExtras().containsKey("userProfile o lo que hayas enviado")). Haslo y edita la pregunta, agrega tambien el resultado si se te cae o si el Logcat da un error que nos dé pistas para ayudarte.

Comment: @JavierAguilar no obtengas los datos dentro de onClick() ya que getArguments() obtendrá un valor null. obten el valor de getArguments() al cargar tu Fragment, por ejemplo dentro de onCreate().

Comment: @GustavoMora el problema es que la pregunta que refieres, no tiene marcada una respuesta como solución.

Answer (score -1):

Dentro de este listener no se podrán obtener, por esa razón extras tiene un valor null:

```
bSiguiente.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Bundle extras = getArguments();
            String s = extras.getString("userprofile");
            ...
            ...
```

Puedes obtener los datos como otra opción dentro de `onCreate()` y usarlos en cualquier otra parte de la aplicación, por ejemplo dentro del listener.

```
private String s = "";

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         Bundle extras = getArguments();
         s = extras.getString("userprofile");
         ...
         ...

     bSiguiente.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //Bundle extras = getArguments();
            //String s = extras.getString("userprofile");

            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Folio: "+ s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            FragmentTransaction trans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            trans.replace(R.id.contenedor, new CapturarInstalaciones7Fragment());
            trans.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
            trans.addToBackStack(null);
            trans.commit();

        }
    });


   }
```

Comment: Hola, primero que nada, agradezco tu respuesta. Hice lo que comentabas, en el fragmento donde envio lo deje igual (en el metodo onClick). Y en el fragmento donde lo recibe, cree el metodo onCreate, pero persiste el error. Al momento de llegar al fragmento donde recibe, la app se ciera y el log marca el mismo error que mencionaba arriba. ¿Cual podria ser el error?